# Interview question about various pointer size under 32bit architecture

Tags: c, sizeof

```
char str[] = " http://www.ibegroup.com/";

char *p = str ;

void Foo ( char str[100]){

}

void *p = malloc( 100 );
```

What's the `sizeof` `str`,`p`,`str`,`p` in the above 4 case in turn?

I've tested it under my machine(which seems to be 64bit) with these results:

```
25 8 8 8
```

But don't understand the reason yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sizeof(char[])` returns the number of bytes in the string, i.e. `strlen()+1` for null-terminated C strings filling the entire array. [Arrays don't decay to pointers in `sizeof`](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/practdiff.html). `str` is an array, and the string has 25 characters plus a null byte, so `sizeof(str)` should be 26. Did you add a space to the value?

The size of a pointer is of course always determined just by the machine architecture, so both instances of `p` are 8 bytes on 64-bit architectures and 4 bytes on 32-bit architectures.

In function arguments, arrays [**do**](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrparam.html) decay to pointers, so you're getting the same result that you get for a pointer. Therefore, the following definitions are equivalent:

```
void foo(char s[42]) {};
void foo(char s[100]) {};
void foo(char* s) {};
```

Comment: @phihag,what's the rationale for `In function arguments, arrays do decay to pointers`?

Comment: array(`char []`) and pointers(`char *`) are essentially the same thing,why treated differently? I'm expecting both are the same value...

Comment: @Je Rog arrays and pointers are **not** the same thing. Please follow the links to the C FAQ, the whole chapter  discusses this in detail. In short, arrays become (or "decay" to) pointers in all contexts *except* `sizeof`, `&` and array initialization.

Comment: @Je Rog A `char*` and a `char[]` cannot ever have the same value, since they are of different types. They can, however, refer to the same position in memory.

Comment: `sizeof STRING_LITERAL` is not necessarily equal to `strlen(STRING_LITERAL) + 1`: imagine `#define STRING_LITERAL "foo\x00bar"`

Comment: @pmg Updated, this is indeed only true if the string is null-terminated and completely fills the array.

Comment: @phihag ,How would you declare a pointer to `&array` regarding this article? http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryvsadr.html

Comment: @Je Rog A pointer to `&array` would be a `char** par[] = &&array;`, a pointer to `array` `char* par[] = &array;`.

Comment: @phihag ,I'm getting this error while doing `char *p3 [] = &str;`, `error: invalid initializer`

Comment: @Je Rog Sorry, my mistake. You need to put `*p3` in parentheses. The result is completely meaningless unless you're dealing with multi-dimensional arrays though. In detail: http://c-faq.com/aryptr/ptrtoarray.html

Comment: @Everyone: I'm a newbie but everyone is wrong about the string being 24 char plus 1 null.  There are 25 real characters in that string -- count them.  The length of a string does not include the null.  Also, look at man strlen and see that it returns "the number of characters that precede the terminating NUL character."

Comment: @grok12 That's what the third sentence in this answer says, isn't it? And the first sentence says `sizeof() == strlen()+1`. For example, for "ab", `sizeof() = 3 == strlen()+1 = 2 + 1`.

Comment: @phihag: Well, he's saying the answer should be 26 because of the null character.  But the answer of 25 is correct since the null char doesn't count in the length.

Comment: @grok12 `sizeof` does not care about the values of bytes in the `char[]`. Therefore, the `sizeof(" http://www.ibegroup.com/") == 26`, and `sizeof("ab") == 3`. The null character does not count for **`strlen`**, that's why `strlen("ab") == 2` and +1 is added to the result of `strlen` to get that of `sizeof` in my above comment and my answer.

Comment: @phihag: Well, now I'm really confused because I tried your "ab" example and it does return 3 just like you said.  But there are 25 real characters in his string.  I tried to run OP's code by my (OSX) compiler but it won't compile and complains about stray '\342' in program along with others.  So I guess there are bad characters in the string which I copied and pasted.  However I did carefully replace each char by typing over it but still got the same result.  But I'm sure now that I am wrong and you are right about sizeof including the null.  But I don't know what to make of the OP's string.

Comment: @grok12 The OP string starts with a space, don't forget to count that. Also, it is rendered with smart quotes, probably an artifact of a translation through a WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: @phihag: I found my problem with his string.  A missing ; (I did tell you I'm a newbie!).  I ran it and the answer is 26.  So I'll slink back into my cave and not come out for a while.

Answer (score 1):

The first is the `sizeof` of an built-in array, which is the amount of elements (24 + null on the end of the string).

The second is the `sizeof` of a pointer which is the native word size of your system, in your case 64 bit or 8 bytes.

The third is the `sizeof` of a pointer to the first element of an array which has the same size as any other pointer, the native word size of your system. Why a pointer to the first element of an array? Because size information of an array goes lost when passed to a function and it gets implicitly converted to a pointer to the first element instead.

The fourth is the `sizeof` of a pointer which has the same size as any other pointer.

Comment: Pedantically speaking, not all pointers are necessarily the same size.

Comment: pmg: Dang, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241205/are-all-data-pointers-of-the-same-size-in-one-platform/1241314#1241314. Should I edit my answer or does this go out of the scope of the question?

Comment: I'd edit the answer (lol). Point is, there is wrong information in the answer. I'd sleep bad at night knowing I left (**confirmed**) [wrong information](http://xkcd.com/386/) hanging around.

Comment: A byte in C is not necessarily 8 bits.

Comment: @paxdiablo I never claimed it is, generally. I only mentioned that it is for the asker's system.

Comment: Point taken. On re-reading, I may well have misunderstood. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

`str` is an array of 8-bit characters, including null terminator.

`p` is a pointer, which is typically the size of the machine's native word size (32 bit or 64 bit).

The size taken up by a pointer stays constant, regardless of the size of the memory to which it points.

**EDIT**

In c++, arguments that are arrays are passed by reference (which internally is a pointer type), that's why the second instance of `str` has `sizeof` 8.

Comment: why the `sizeof` the 2nd `str` is not 100, like the 1st `str`?

Comment: @Je Rog: Because arrays get "promoted" to pointers when they appear as argument to a function.

Comment: @DarkDust: The promotion to pointer causes all info of the 100 to be lost so all sizeof can do is count out to the first null, right?

Answer (score -1):

in the cases the size of

```
char str[] = “ http://www.ibegroup.com/”
```

is known to be 25 (24+1), because that much memory is actually allocated.

In the case of

```
void Foo ( char str[100]){
```

no memory is allocated