# Struct Pointer Not Providing the Correct Size in sizeof() method

Tags: objective-c, struct, malloc

I'm having a issue getting the size of a struct pointer after allocating the memory using malloc or realloc. I've worked around this by keeping track of the memory in a separate counter, but I would like to know if this is a bug or if there is a way to properly query the size of a struct pointer.

Sample code demonstrates that no matter how much memory I allocate to the struct pointer it always returns 4 when querying using the sizeof() method.

```
typedef struct {
    int modelID;
    int bufferPosition;
    int bufferSize;
} Model;

Model *models = malloc(10000 * sizeof(Model));

NSLog(@"sizeof(models) = %lu", sizeof(models)); //this prints: sizeof(models) = 4
```

Comment: Please tag this Objective C and not C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to get at the size of the allocated buffer.

`sizeof` if the wrong way to go since it is evaluated at compile time. The size of the buffer is a runtime concept.

You would need a way to query you C library to return the allocation size for the pointer to the buffer.

Some systems have a way to get that kind of information, for instance `malloc_size` on Mac OS.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. To get it to work for iOS I had to import malloc/malloc.h, after that it all seems to be working now. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

4 is the correct answer, because "models" is a pointer, and pointers are 4 bytes. You will not be able to find the length of an array this way. Any reason you're not using NSArray?

Answer (score 1):

4 is the correct answer. 
Pointers point to a memory location which could contain anything. When you are querying the size of a pointer, it gives the size of the memory location which holds the pointer, which in your case is 4.

For example

```
int *a = pointing to some large number;

int *b = pointing to a single digit number;
```

In the above case, both a and b have the same size irrespective of where they are pointing to.

For more information, have a look at this post [size of a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751749/size-of-a-pointer)

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof(myvar)` will return size of pointer. in 32bit environment it equals to 4(bytes).
why don't you use `sizeof (Model)` instead?