# Double pointer conversions, passing into function with `const void **ptr` parameter

Tags: c, pointers, gcc

GCC gives me folowing warning:

```
note: expected 'const void **' but argument is of type 'const struct auth **
```

Is there any case, where it could cause problems?

Bigger snippet is

```
struct auth *current;
gl_list_iterator_next(&it, &current, NULL);
```

Function just stores in `current` some `void *` pointer.

Comment: did you try casting it to void?

Comment: Casting means, that I say to compiler `Trust me. I know better`. But I am not.

Comment: what's the method signature for `gl_list_iterator_next()`?

Comment: `static inline bool
gl_list_iterator_next (gl_list_iterator_t *iterator,
                       const void **eltp, gl_list_node_t *nodep)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error message is clear enough: you are passing a `struct auth **` where a `void **` was accepted. There is no implicit conversion between these types as a `void*` may not have the same size and alignment as other pointer types.

The solution is to use an intermediate `void*`:

```
void *current_void;
struct auth *current;

gl_list_iterator_next(&it, &current_void, NULL);
current = current_void;
```

**EDIT**: to address the comments below, here's an example of why this is necessary. Suppose you're on a platform where `sizeof(struct auth*) == sizeof(short) == 2`, while `sizeof(void*) == sizeof(long) == 4`; that's allowed by the C standard and platforms with varying pointer sizes actually exist. Then the OP's code would be similar to doing

```
short current;
long *p = (long *)(&current);  // cast added, similar to casting to void**

// now call a function that does writes to *p, as in
*p = 0xDEADBEEF;               // undefined behavior!
```

However, this program too can be made to work by introducing an intermediate `long` (although the result may only be meaningful when the `long`'s value is small enough to store in a `short`).

Comment: how is using an intermediate `void*` different from just casting it, assuming he isn't using the original `*current` for anything else?

Comment: If the alignment of `void*` could be different, how is that issue mitigated when you assign the pointer back to your `struct auth*` type?  In other words if the function returns a `void*` to memory that is of a different alignment, and you simply assigned that pointer back to a `struct auth*`, shouldn't there be some type of compensation for the lack of alignment? Or is it simply the case that the alignment for `void*` is always a superset of any other pointer type's alignment requirements, so any other pointer will be compatible with `void*` alignment?

Comment: @Jason: when you say `current = current_void`, the compiler inserts a conversion from `void*` to `struct auth*` if necessary. Such a conversion is guaranteed to exist for all data pointer types (but not for function pointers, IIRC), because `void*` was designed to be a universal pointer type.

Comment: @Kache: the difference is that the intermediate `void*` serves as a location where a value of type `void*` can be stored through indirection of a `void**`. Suppose that a `struct auth*` would be smaller than `void*` on some platform (which may happen), then the OP's code + a cast might write past the end of `&current`. It's as if you'd cast a `short*` to a `long*` and then store a `long` through indirection.

Comment: It is very intresting. May I ask for example, under which OS, processor and other conditions, `sizeof(void *) != sizeof(foo *)`?

Comment: @illusionoflife: mostly word-addressed machines and those with segmented memory models. Those are rare, but the C standard still caters to them. See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/6751749/166749 and questions linked there.

Comment: Whoa, didn't know that pointer size mismatch could happen. Not only that, you'd have to know that using the "larger" temporary container is safe b/c of the guaranteed data pointer type conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Hm... I think constructs like `const void *` doesn't makes much sense.

Because if user wants to access data under `void *` he needs casting from void, and this action bypasses compiler type checks and consequently - constantness.

Consider this example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () {

  int i = 6;
  int * pi = &i;

  const void * pcv = pi;
  const int  * pci = pi;

  // casting avoids type checker, so constantness is irrelevant here
  *(int *)pcv = 7;

  // here we don't need casting, and thus compiler is able to guard read-only data
  *pci = 7;

  return 0;
}
```

So conclusion is that we need either void pointer Or to ensure constantness of data, but not both.

Comment: You are not right. `void *` can be implicityle morphed to `foo *`, but `const void *` can not.

Comment: My point was that `const` is very useful for getting compile-time error if somebody tries to modify read-only data. But this purpose is bypassed with construct `const void *` - because you can't modify data under `void*` without casting it to some concrete pointer. If you do so - type checker is bypassed as well as constantness. In the end user is able to modify read-only data without getting compile-time error. This was my point why `const void *` is bad thing.

Comment: Void * is perfectly good. I do not need cast to use it, I use assignment.