# Is casting to pointers to pointers to void always safe?

Tags: c, pointers, void

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(void *v[], int i, int j)
{
    void *tmp;

    tmp = v[i];
    v[i] = v[j];
    v[j] = tmp;
}

int main(void)
{
    char *s[] = {"one", "two"};
    printf("%s, %s\n", s[0], s[1]);
    swap(s, 0, 1);
    printf("%s, %s\n", s[0], s[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**:

```
one, two

two, one
```

**Warning:** `no compatible pointer casting, need void**, but char`

I used this program to simulate the swap function in **K&R**, to demonstrate the use of the  function pointer, and my question is whether the cast of the `void pointer` is always safe, or if there is any way to replace it.

Comment: i use gcc std=c99 to compile it.

Comment: what really is happening is, pointers are like handles or addresses.. you are not swapping the data, you are swapping the address to the data. So, it is quite safe.

Comment: @Aniket: No, this is not necessarily safe.  Imagine a system where `char*` is a different size than `int*`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it is not necessarily safe to pass a `char**` where a `void**` (which is what a `void*[]` function parameter actually is) is expected.  The fact that the compiler makes you perform an explicit cast is a hint about that.

In practice, it is likely to be fine.  Strictly speaking, however, you usually have no guarantee that `sizeof (T*) == sizeof (U*)` for distinct types `T` and `U`. (For example, you could imagine a hypothetical system where `sizeof (int*) < sizeof (char*)` because pointers-to-`int` are aligned and therefore don't need to store the least significant bits.) Consequently, your `swap` function might index into the `v` array using the wrong offsets.

Also see Q4.9 from the comp.lang.c FAQ: [Can I give the formal parameter type `void **`, and do something like this?](http://www.c-faq.com/ptrs/genericpp.html)

To call `swap` safely, you should do something like:

```
void* temp[] = { &s[0], &s[1] };
swap(temp, 0, 1);
```

although that would swap the elements of `temp`, not of `s`.

If you're authoring `swap`, in general you should make such a function take a `void*` argument (instead of a `void**` one) and a `size_t` argument that specifies the size of each element.  Your function then could cast the `void*` to `char*` safely and swap individual bytes:

```
void swap(void* p, size_t elementSize, size_t i, size_t j)
{
    char* item1 = p;
    char* item2 = p;

    item1 += i * elementSize;
    item2 += j * elementSize;

    while (elementSize-- > 0) {
        char temp = *item1;
        *item1 = *item2;
        *item2 = temp;
        item1++;
        item2++;
    }
}
```

Edit:
Also see [this StackOverflow answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12621277/179715).

Comment: brilliant anwser!thank you,jamesdlin, but in my computer, all pointers seem to be equivalent, and i followed your link,found [http://www.c-faq.com/null/machexamp.html], this is what i want to find.

Comment: @pupu007 Even if equal, you are still invoking undefined behavior in your program, if you use the code from your question.

Comment: There **is** a guarantee that `sizeof(char*)==sizeof(void*)`.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. No there isn't. Not according to ISO C (and this answer). Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: @BenjaminCrawfordCtrl-Alt-Tut https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p28

Comment: Oh wow, lots of contradictory stuff out there. I heard `void*` must be big enough to hold _all_ pointer types, so it makes sense that it's the same size as the smallest addressable type's pointer.

Answer (score -1):

You need to typecast the pointer in swap call.  Change it to `swap ( ( void * )s, 0, 1 );`

Comment: @Jens Gustedt: Is ( void * )s changing from void * to a different type?

Comment: `( void * )s` by itself not, but since the first parameter of `swap` is `void**` an implicit conversion to that is taking place immediately after the explicit cast and before calling the function.

Comment: @unxnut: You're essentially casting `char**` => `void*` => `void**`. `char**` and `void**` are not the same type.

Comment: No, the code is just casting char * => void * and swapping the void * pointers, effectively swapping the char * pointers.  It does not dereference the void * pointers in any way.

Comment: @unxnut: No, `swap` takes a `void**`.  And while it does not dereference a `void*` type, it does dereference `void**` (via `v[i]` and `v[j]`) and assumes that `sizeof (void*) == sizeof (char*)`.

Answer (score -1):

To avoid the warning call the function as follows,

```
swap((void *) s, 0, 1);
```

It is always safe to cast any pointer as a void pointer.

Comment: You're actually casting a `char**` to a `void*` which then is being implicitly cast to a `void**`.  Casting a `T**` to a `void**` is not necessarily safe.

Comment: This answer is wrong. Converting **to** `void*` is always safe, but the implicit conversion from `void*` to a different type than the original isn't.

Comment: @JensGustedt why? some computers make that different representations for pointers to different types.So void *[] may make a worry pointing to char *[]

Comment: @pupu007 a function parameter of `void*[]` is equivalent to a `void**`. I don't understand your use of "worry".