# A good and idiomatic way to use GCC and clang __attribute__((cleanup)) and pointer declarations

Tags: c, gcc, clang

I think that GCC extension [`__attribute__((cleanup))`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Variable-Attributes.html) is a good idea, at least for some cases, but i can't figure out how to use it in a good way. All i'm doing looks still really annoying.

I saw a lot of code doing `#define _cleanup_(x) __attribute__((cleanup(x))` just to type less, but it there a way to pass there a standard function like `free` or `closedir`, `fclose`, etc?

As I see I can't just write:

```
__attribute__((cleanup(free))) char *foo = malloc(10);
```

Because the cleanup callback will receive `char**` pointer, and I have to always write something like:

```
static void free_char(char **ptr) { free(*ptr); }
__cleanup__((free_char)) char *foo = malloc(10);
```

That's pretty annoying, and the most annoying part is to define such cleanup functions for all types you need, because obviously you can't just define it for `void **`. What is the best way to avoid these things?

Comment: I think you've made a pretty good case for saying that `__attribute__((cleanup))` is **not** a good idea.

Comment: If you want destructors you know where to find them.

Comment: @user3386109, i'd say it IS a good idea, but the realisation is a little bit broken. Or maybe there is something i don't understand, so that's why I'm asking.

Comment: @coredump The realization is fine too. That the cleanup function expects a _pointer_ to the variable makes sense, because the variable may not be a pointer itself but a large struct that is better not passed by value (cf. the difference between glib's `g_autoptr` and `g_auto`). Having two different attributes just for convenience would needlessly bloat the language extension.

Comment: @RossRidge: better to have control over it than to worry about the baggage C++ brings to the table.  So yes, if we want reasonable, good, non-hidden destructors, we know where to find them: C code under gcc and clang.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's a library that builds general-purpose smart pointers (`unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr`) on top of `__attribute__((cleanup))` here: https://github.com/Snaipe/libcsptr

It allows you to write higher-level code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <csptr/smart_ptr.h>
#include <csptr/array.h>

void print_int(void *ptr, void *meta) {
    (void) meta;
    // ptr points to the current element
    // meta points to the array metadata (global to the array), if any.
    printf("%d\n", *(int*) ptr);
}

int main(void) {
    // Destructors for array types are run on every element of the
    // array before destruction.
    smart int *ints = unique_ptr(int[5], {5, 4, 3, 2, 1}, print_int);
    // ints == {5, 4, 3, 2, 1}

    // Smart arrays are length-aware
    for (size_t i = 0; i < array_length(ints); ++i) {
        ints[i] = i + 1;
    }
    // ints == {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

    return 0;
}
```

As for idiomatic, though? Well the above is certainly close to idiomatic C++. Not C so much. The feature is clearly mainly supported in GCC and Clang because they have C++ compilers as well, so they have the option to make use of the RAII machinery in the C frontend at no extra cost; that doesn't make it a great idea to write C-intended-as-C this way. It kinda relies on a C++ compiler being *present* despite not actually being *used*.

If it were me, I'd probably investigate implementing autorelease pools, or something similar that can actually be done in pure C at the language level. Depends how quickly you need your resources to be freed; for memory, you usually can live without immediate cleanup.

Answer (score 23):

You can't write `__attribute__((cleanup(free)))`, but you don't need to write a `free` cleanup function for each type. It's ugly, but you can write this:

```
static void cleanup_free(void *p) {
  free(*(void**) p);
}
```

I first saw this [in the `systemd` codebase](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/5809f340fd7e5e6c76e229059c50d92e1f57e8d8/src/basic/alloc-util.h#L50-L54).

For other functions you would in general need to a write a wrapper with an extra level of indirection for use with `__attribute__((cleanup))`. `systemd` [defines a helper macro for this](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/5809f340fd7e5e6c76e229059c50d92e1f57e8d8/src/basic/macro.h#L361-L366):

```
#define DEFINE_TRIVIAL_CLEANUP_FUNC(type, func)             \
    static inline void func##p(type *p) {                   \
            if (*p)                                         \
                    func(*p);                               \
    }                                                       \
    struct __useless_struct_to_allow_trailing_semicolon__
```

which is used [all over the place](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=DEFINE_TRIVIAL_CLEANUP_FUNC), e.g.

```
DEFINE_TRIVIAL_CLEANUP_FUNC(FILE*, pclose);

#define _cleanup_pclose_ __attribute__((cleanup(pclosep)))
```

Comment: It might be worth noting that `cleanup_free` performs a conversion from `T**` => `void*` => `void**` that [(strictly speaking) isn't necessarily safe to do portably](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16557330/179715), which is why the explicit `*(void**)` dance is necessary.