# How to implement Go's defer() in C so that it allows declaring vars?

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor, c11, gcc-extensions

In this [Modern C](https://invidious.snopyta.org/watch?v=QpAhX-gsHMs) video there's a trick that allows to postpone execution of a code until the block/scope exits. It's used as follows:

```
int main()
{
    int foo=0, bar;
    const char *etc = "Some code before defer";

    defer(profile_begin(), profile_end())
    {
        /* Some code, which will be automatically 
         * preceded by call to profile_begin() and
         * followed by run of profile_end().*/
         foo++;
         bar = 1;
    }

    etc = "Some code after defer";
    foo = bar + 1;
}
```

Implementation from the video:

```
#define macro_var_line(name) concat(name, __LINE__)
#define defer(start,end) for( \
        int macro_var_line(done) = (start,0); \
        !macro_var_line(done); \
        (macro_var_line(done) += 1), end)
```

It's pretty simply implemented. What might be confusing is the `macro_var_line(name)` macro. Its purpose is to simply ensure that a temporary variable will have a unique, "obfuscated" name by adding current line number to it (of where defer is called).

However the problem is that one cannot pass code to `start` snippet that declares new variables, because it is pasted in the for() comma operator that uses `int` type  (the `int macro_var_line(done) = …`). So it's not possible to, eg.:

```
defer(FILE *f = fopen("log.txt","a+"), fclose(f))
{
    fprintf(f,"Some message, f=%p",f);
}
```

I would want to have such macro, capable of declaring new vars in `start` snippet. Is it achievable with standard C99, C11 or maybe some GCC extensions?

**UPDATE**: I've found a solution utilizing GCC nested functions. Basically, the `{ bblock }` that's following the `defer()` macro becomes nested function body. And it's possible to forward declare the nested function and invoke it from before the block, i.e.:

```
#define defer(start,end) \
                auto void var_line(routine) (void); \
                start; \
                /* Invoke above predeclared void routine_123(void) function */ \
                var_line(routine)(); \
                end; \
                /* Define the nested function */ \                    
                void var_line(routine) (void)
```

**UPDATE2**: Here's an elegant version which:

1. runs first leading statements as start and the last one as the end code,
2. runs the very first statement in its own `for()`/declarative space,
3. runs the block properly via an `if(cond == 0)` check/block start up.

---

```
#define defer(...) \
    for (int var_line(cond) = 0; var_line(cond) == 0; ) \
        for (FIRST_ARG(__VA_ARGS__); var_line(cond) == 0; ) \
            for (SKIP_LAST_ARG(SKIP_FIRST_ARG(__VA_ARGS__)); \
                var_line(cond) == 0; \
                    var_line(cond) += 1 ) \
                for (int var_line(cond_int) = 0; \
                    var_line(cond_int) <= 1; \
                        var_line(cond_int) += 1 ) \
                    if (var_line(cond_int) == 1) \
                    { \
                        LAST_ARG(__VA_ARGS__); \
                    } else if (var_line(cond_int) == 0)
```

Comment: What exactly is the point?  Why is using such a convoluted construct better than just writing `profile_begin(); { /* ... */ } profile_end();`?  And why build something even more convoluted instead of just writing what you want naturally?

Comment: One point is that such remote pairing of snippets of code is hard and requires extra focus. And the implementation is actually very basic, not convoluted.

Comment: Not as hard to a C programmer as recognizing what `defer()` is supposed to do.  It is usually a mistake to try to impose the idioms and conventions of one language on another language that has different ones.  If the block is so long that it presents a challenge to match the prolog with the epilogue, then a better C solution would be to move it to a separate function, so that only a function call appears between.

Comment: In fact, if the block is so long that matching prologue to epilogue is an issue, then I'd say that the `defer()` just changes that to a problem of associating the epilogue with the end of the block.

Comment: there is a slight hope that "defer" mechanism will be added to a new C standard. There is a proposal for it. see http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2542.pdf

Comment: The above macro can well  be used for your use case. You just need two pairs of braces, assuming you want to limit the scope of f: `{ FILE *f = fopen("log.txt", "a+"); if(!f){...} defer(0, fclose(f)){ something; } }`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger deferred executions are dynamically stacked, and are executed even when a function returns prematurely. Basically the construct is a finction-level `atexit`. So one can write something like `if (allocate resource) defer(cleanup resource) else return failure; ` many times in the function and not worry about complicated cleanup logic.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem., *Go's* `defer` may have those characteristics, but neither the OP's macro nor anything else that can be implemented in standard C17 does.  I'm not criticizing this or any feature of Go.  I am criticizing use of a C macro to produce a pale imitation.

Comment: I would avoid evil macros like this. Ask yourself why you can't do `profile_begin(); function(); profile_end();` instead? Too simple, too readable, too maintainable?

Answer (score 6):

As I expressed in comments, my recommendation is to avoid using such a thing in the first place.  Whatever your video might have said or implied, the prevailing opinion among modern C programmers is that macro usage should be minimized.  Variable-like macros should generally represent context-independent constant values, and function-like macros are usually better implemented as actual functions.  That's not to say that all macro use must be avoided, but most modern C professionals look poorly on complex macros, and your `defer()` is complex enough to qualify.

Additionally, you do yourself no favors by trying to import the style and idioms of other languages into C.  The common idioms of each language become established because they work well for that language, not, generally, because they have inherent intrinsic value.  I advise you to learn C and the idioms that C programmers use, as opposed to how to write C code that looks like Go.

With that said, let's consider your `defer()` macro.  You write,

> However the problem is that one cannot pass code to start snippet that declares new variables

, but in fact the restriction is stronger than that.  Because the macro uses the `start` argument in a comma expression (`start,0`), it needs to be an expression itself.  Declarations or complete statements of any kind are not allowed.  That's only indirectly related to that expression appearing in the first clause of a `for` statement's control block.  (The same applies to the `end` argument, too.)

It may also be important to note that the macro expands to code that fails evaluate the `end` expression if execution of the associated statement terminates by branching out of the block via a `return` or `goto` statement, or by executing a function that does not return, such as `exit()` or `longjmp()`.  Additionally, unlike with Go's `defer`, the `end` expression is evaluated *in full* after the provided statement -- no part of it is evaluated before, which might surprise a Go programmer.  These are characteristics of the options presented below, too.

If you want to pass only the `start` and `end` as macro arguments, and you want to allow declarations to appear in `start`, then you could do this:

```
// Option 1
#define defer(start,end) start; for( \
        int macro_var_line(done) = 0; \
        !done; \
        (macro_var_line(done) += 1), (end))
```

That moves `start` out of the `for` statement in the macro's replacement text, to a position where arbitrary C code may appear.  Do note, however, that any variable declarations will then be scoped to the innermost containing block.

If you want to limit the scope of your declarations then there is also this alternative and variations on it, which I find much more straightforward than the original:

```
// Option 2
#define defer(start, end, body) { start; body end; }
```

You would use that like so:

```
defer(FILE *f = fopen("log.txt","a+"), fclose(f), // argument list continues ...
    fprintf(f,"Some message, f=%p",f);
);
```

That is somewhat tuned to your particular example, in that it assumes that the body is given as a sequence of zero or more complete statements (which can include blocks, flow-control statements, *etc*).  As you can see, it also requires the body to be passed as a macro argument instead of appearing after the macro invocation, but I consider that an advantage, because it facilitates recognizing the point where the deferred code kicks in.

Comment: Option 2 will fail if `body` contains a comma not inside parentheses, because it will be parsed as two arguments.  For instance, if `body` were something like `{ int x,y; /* do stuff with x and y */ }`

Comment: Yes, @NateEldredge, that is a limitation of option 2.  It can be accommodated, albeit sometimes more comfortably than other times.  My overall recommendation remains "don't do this".

Answer (score 3):

There is actually an effort in the standard's committee to standardize a `defer` feature. The [paper proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2589.pdf) also comes with a [reference implementation](https://gustedt.gitlabpages.inria.fr/defer/). The idea is to propose such a feature that may be implemented with the least compiler magic possible.

If all goes to plan, that feature could even be rebase on lambdas, if we get these into C23 in time.

Comment: Alas C23 defer has not materialized.  This is a pity since using C32 lambda to implement C23 defer in a compiler seems "an easy thing to do".

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate `defer` by using the `__attribute__((cleanup(...)))` feature of GCC and Clang. Also see this [SO question about `free`ing a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34574933/a-good-and-idiomatic-way-to-use-gcc-and-clang-attribute-cleanup-and-point).

For instance:

```c
// the following are some utility functions and macros

#define defer(fn) __attribute__((cleanup(fn)))

void cleanup_free(void* p) {
  free(*((void**) p));
}
#define defer_free defer(cleanup_free)

void cleanup_file(FILE** fp) {
  if (*fp == NULL) { return; }
  fclose(*fp);
}
#define defer_file defer(cleanup_file)



// here's our code:

void foo(void) {
  // here's some memory allocation
  defer_free int* arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
  if (arr == NULL) { return; }

  // some file opening
  defer_file FILE* fp1 = fopen("file1.txt", "rb");
  if (fp1 == NULL) { return; }

  // other file opening
  defer_file FILE* fp2 = fopen("file2.txt", "rb");
  if (fp2 == NULL) { return; }

  // rest of the code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a trick from "Smart Template Container for C". See [link](https://github.com/tylov/STC/blob/master/include/stc/ccommon.h#L140).

```c
#define c_autovar(declvar, ...) for (declvar, *_c_ii = NULL; !_c_ii; ++_c_ii, __VA_ARGS__)
```

Basically you declare a variable and hijack it's type to form a NULL pointer. This pointer is used as a guard to ensure that the loop is executed only once.
Incrementing NULL pointer is likely *Undefined Behavior* because the standard only allows to form a pointer pointing just *after* an object and NULL points to no object. However, it's likely run everywhere.

I guess you could get rid of *UB* by adding a global variable:

```
int defer_guard;
```

And setting the guard pointer to a pointer to `defer_guard` in the increment statement.

```
extern int defer_guard;

#define defer_var(declvar, cleanup)           \
    for (declvar, *_c_ii = NULL;              \
    !_c_ii;                                   \
    _c_ii = (void*)&defer_guard, cleanup)
```

It will work fine when invoked as:

```
defer_var(FILE *f = fopen("log.txt","a+"), fclose(f))
{
    fprintf(f,"Some message, f=%p",f);
}
```

---

**EDIT**

Actually it is possible to derive a macro that will accept both `expression` and `declaration` as `start`. One must use **two** `for` loops instead of one.

```c
#define DEFER(start, end)        \
    for (int _done = 0; !_done;) \
    for (start; !(_done++); end)

int main() {
    DEFER(FILE *f = fopen("log.txt","a+"), fclose(f)) {
        fprintf(f,"Some message, f=%p", (void*)f);
    }
    FILE *f;
    DEFER(f = fopen("log.txt","a+"), fclose(f)) {
        fprintf(f,"Some message, f=%p", (void*)f);
    }
    return 0;
}
```