# Why is this claimed dereferencing type-punned pointer warning compiler-specific?

Tags: c, pointers, casting

I've read [various](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8824622/fix-for-dereferencing-type-punned-pointer-will-break-strict-aliasing) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163126/dereferencing-type-punned-pointer-will-break-strict-aliasing-rules-warning) [on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246228/dereferencing-type-punned-pointer-will-break-strict-aliasing-rules) [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7630150/dereferencing-type-punned-pointer-will-break-strict-aliasing-rules) RE: the derefercing type-punned pointer error. My understanding is that the error is essentially the compiler warning of the danger of accessing an object through a pointer of a different type (though an exception appears to be made for `char*`), which is an understandable and reasonable warning.

My question is specific to the code below: **why does casting the address of a pointer to a `void**` qualify for this warning (promoted to error via `-Werror`)?**

**Moreover, this code is compiled for multiple target architectures, only one of which generates the warning/error - might this imply that it is legitimately a compiler version-specific deficiency?**

```
// main.c
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Foo
{
  int i;
} Foo;

void freeFunc( void** obj )
{
  if ( obj && * obj )
  {
    free( *obj );
    *obj = NULL;
  }
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  Foo* f = calloc( 1, sizeof( Foo ) );
  freeFunc( (void**)(&f) );

  return 0;
}
```

If my understanding, stated above, is correct, a `void**`, being still just a pointer, this should be safe casting.

Is there a workaround *not using lvalues* that would pacify this compiler-specific warning/error? I.e. I understand that and why this will resolve the issue, but I would like to avoid this approach because I want to take advantage of `freeFunc()` *NULL*ing an intended out-arg:

```
void* tmp = f;
freeFunc( &tmp );
f = NULL;
```

Problem compiler (one of one):

```
user@8d63f499ed92:/build$ /usr/local/crosstool/x86-fc3/bin/i686-fc3-linux-gnu-gcc --version && /usr/local/crosstool/x86-fc3/bin/i686-fc3-linux-gnu-gcc -Wall -O2 -Werror ./main.c
i686-fc3-linux-gnu-gcc (GCC) 3.4.5
Copyright (C) 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

./main.c: In function `main':
./main.c:21: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules

user@8d63f499ed92:/build$
```

Not-complaining compiler (one of many):

```
user@8d63f499ed92:/build$ /usr/local/crosstool/x86-rh73/bin/i686-rh73-linux-gnu-gcc --version && /usr/local/crosstool/x86-rh73/bin/i686-rh73-linux-gnu-gcc -Wall -O2 -Werror ./main.c
i686-rh73-linux-gnu-gcc (GCC) 3.2.3
Copyright (C) 2002 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

user@8d63f499ed92:/build$
```

---

Update: I've further discovered the warning appears to be generated specifically when compiled with `-O2` (still with the noted "problem compiler" only)

Comment: Also see: [Is casting to pointers to pointers to void always safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16556443/179715)

Comment: _"a `void**`, being still just a pointer, this should be safe casting."_ Woah there skippy! Sounds like you have some fundamental assumptions going on. Try to think less in terms of bytes and levers and more in terms of abstractions, because that's what you're actually programming with

Comment: Tangentially, the compilers you are using are **15** and **17** years old!  I would not rely on either one.

Comment: @TavianBarnes Also, if you must rely on GCC 3 for any reason, it's best to use the end-of-lifed end version, which was 3.4.6, I think.  Why not take advantage of all the available fixes to that series before it was laid to rest.

Comment: What kind of C++ coding standard prescribes all those spaces?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

A value of type `void**` is a pointer to an object of type `void*`. An object of type `Foo*` is not an object of type `void*`.

There is an implicit conversion between *values* of type `Foo*` and `void*`. This conversion may change the representation of the value. Similarly, you can write `int n = 3; double x = n;` and this has the well-defined behavior of setting `x` to the value `3.0`, but `double *p = (double*)&n;` has undefined behavior (and in practice will not set `p` to a “pointer to `3.0`” on any common architecture).

Architectures where different types of pointers to objects have different representations are rare nowadays, but they are permitted by the C standard. There are (rare) old machines with *word pointers* which are addresses of a word in memory and *byte pointers* which are addresses of a word together with a byte offset in this word; `Foo*` would be a word pointer and `void*` would be a byte pointer on such architectures. There are (rare) machines with *fat pointers* which contain information not only about the address of the object, but also about its type, its size and its access control lists; a pointer to a definite type might have a different representation from a `void*` which needs additional type information at runtime.

Such machines are rare, but permitted by the C standard. And some C compilers take advantage of the permission to treat type-punned pointers as distinct to optimize code. The risk of pointers aliasing is a major limitation to a compiler's ability to optimize code, so compilers tend to take advantage of such permissions.

A compiler is free to tell you that you're doing something wrong, or to quietly do what you didn't want, or to quietly do what you wanted. Undefined behavior allows any of these.

You can make `freefunc` a macro:

```
#define FREE_SINGLE_REFERENCE(p) (free(p), (p) = NULL)
```

This comes with the usual limitations of macros: lack of type safety, `p` is evaluated twice. Note that this only gives you the safety of not leaving dangling pointers around if `p` was the single pointer to the freed object.

Comment: And it's good to know that even if `Foo*` and `void*` have the same representation on your architecture, *it's still undefined* to type-pun them.

Answer (score 12):

A `void *` is treated specially by the C standard in part because it references an incomplete type.  This treatment does **not** extend to `void **` as it *does* point to a complete type, specifically `void *`.

The strict aliasing rules say you can't convert a pointer of one type to a pointer of another type and subsequently dereference that pointer because doing so means reinterpreting the bytes of one type as another.  The only exception is when converting to a character type which allows you to read the representation of an object.

You can get around this limitation by using a function-like macro instead of a function:

```
#define freeFunc(obj) (free(obj), (obj) = NULL)
```

Which you can call like this:

```
freeFunc(f);
```

This does have a limitation however, because the above macro will evaluate `obj` twice.  If you're using GCC, this can be avoided with some extensions, specifically the `typeof` keyword and statement expressions:

```
#define freeFunc(obj) ({ typeof (&(obj)) ptr = &(obj); free(*ptr); *ptr = NULL; })
```

Comment: +1 for providing a better implementation of the intended behavior. The only problem I see with the `#define` is, that it will evaluate `obj` twice. I don't know a good way of avoiding that second evaluation, though. Even a statement expression (GNU extension) won't do the trick as you need to assign to `obj` after you've used its value.

Comment: @cmaster: If you're willing to use GNU extensions such as statement expressions, then you can use [`typeof`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html) to avoid evaluating `obj` twice: `#define freeFunc(obj) ({ typeof(&(obj)) ptr = &(obj); free(*ptr); *ptr = NULL; })` .

Comment: @ruakh Very cool :-) Would be great if dbush would edit that into the answer, so it won't get mass-deleted with the comments.

Answer (score 9):

Dereferencing a type punned pointer is UB and you can't count on what will happen.

Different compilers generate different warnings, and for this purpose different versions of the same compiler can be considered as different compilers. This seems a better explanation for the variance you see than a dependence on the architecture.

A case which may help you understand why type punning in this case can be bad is that your function won't work on an architecture for which `sizeof(Foo*) != sizeof(void*)`. That is authorized by the standard although I don't know any current one for which this is true.

A workaround would be to use a macro instead of a function.

Note that `free` accepts null pointers.

Comment: Fascinating that it is possible that `sizeof Foo* != sizeof void*`. I've never encountered "in the wild" pointer sizes being type-dependent, so over the years, I've come to consider it axiomatic that pointer sizes are all the same on a given architecture.

Comment: @Stonethrow the standard example is fat pointers used to address bytes in word addressable architecture.  But I think current word addressable machines use the alternative sizeof char == sizeof _word_.

Comment: @StoneThrow: Regardless of pointer sizes, type-based alias analysis makes it unsafe; this helps compilers optimize by assuming that a store through a `float*` won't modify an `int32_t` object, so e.g. an `int32_t*` doesn't need `int32_t *restrict ptr` for the compiler to assume it's not pointing to the same memory.  Same for stores through a `void**` being assumed not to modify a `Foo*` object.

Answer (score 4):

This code is invalid per the C Standard, so it might work in some cases, but is not necessarily portable.

The "strict aliasing rule" for accessing a value via a pointer that has been cast to a different pointer type is found in 6.5 paragraph 7:

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of the following types:
>
> - a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
> - a qualified version of a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the effective type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a qualified version of the effective type of the object,
> - an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its members (including, recursively, a member of a subaggregate or contained union), or
> - a character type.

In your `*obj = NULL;` statement, the object has effective type `Foo*` but is accessed by the lvalue expression `*obj` with type `void*`.

In 6.7.5.1 paragraph 2, we have

> For two pointer types to be compatible, both shall be identically qualified and both shall be pointers to compatible types.

So `void*` and `Foo*` are not compatible types or compatible types with qualifiers added, and certainly don't fit any of the other options of the strict aliasing rule.

Although not the technical reason the code is invalid, it's also relevant to note section 6.2.5 paragraph 26:

> A pointer to `void` shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as a pointer to a character type. Similarly, pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements. All pointers to structure types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as each other. All pointers to union types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as each other. Pointers to other types need not have the same representation or alignment requirements.

As for the differences in warnings, this is not a case where the Standard requires a diagnostic message, so it's just a matter of how good the compiler or its version is at noticing potential issues and pointing them out in a helpful way. You noticed optimization settings can make a difference. This is often because more information is internally generated about how various pieces of the program actually fit together in practice, and that extra information is therefore also available for warning checks.

Answer (score 3):

On top of what the other answers have said, this is a **classic anti-pattern** in C, and one which should be burned with fire. It appears in:

1. Free-and-null-out functions like the one you've found the warning in.
2. Allocation functions that shun the standard C idiom of returning `void *` (which doesn't suffer from this issue because it involves a *value conversion* instead of *type punning*), instead returning an error flag and storing the result via a pointer-to-pointer.

For another example of (1), there was a longstanding infamous case in ffmpeg/libavcodec's `av_free` function. I believe it was eventually fixed with a macro or some other trick, but I'm not sure.

For (2), both [`cudaMalloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7989784/379897) and `posix_memalign` are examples.

In neither case does the interface inherently *require* invalid usage, but it strongly encourages it, and admits correct usage only with an extra temporary object of type `void *` that defeats the purpose of the free-and-null-out functionality, and makes allocation awkward.

Comment: Do you have a link explaining more about why (1) is an anti-pattern? I don't think I'm familiar with this situation/argument and would like to learn more.

Comment: @StoneThrow: It's really simple - the intent is to prevent misuse by nulling out the object storing the pointer to the memory that's being freed, but the only way it can actually do that is if the caller is actually storing the pointer in an object of type `void *` and casting/converting it every time it wants to dereference it. This is very unlikely. If the caller is storing some other type of pointer, the only way to call the function without invoking UB is to copy the pointer to a temp object of type `void *` and pass the address of that to the freeing function, and then it just...

Comment: ...nulls a temp object rather than the actual storage where the caller had the pointer. Of course what actually happens is that users of the function end up doing a `(void **)` cast, producing undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Although C was designed for machines which use the same representation for all pointers, the authors of the Standard wanted to make the language usable on machines that use different representations for pointers to different types of objects.  Therefore, they did not require that machines which use different pointer representations for different kinds of pointers support a "pointer to any kind of pointer" type, even though many machines could do so at zero cost.

Before the Standard was written, implementations for platforms that used the same representation for all pointer types would unanimously allow a `void**` to be used, at least with suitable casting, as a "pointer to any pointer".  The authors of the Standard almost certainly recognized that this would be useful on platforms that supported it, but since it couldn't be universally supported they declined to mandate it.  Instead, they expected that quality implementation would process such constructs as what the Rationale would describe as a "popular extension", in cases where doing so would make sense.