# size difference in various string initializations in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, sizeof

I started learning C and got a question that I could not find the answer to.

When I initialize a random string with

```
char *str1 = "Big";
printf("size of str1: %ld\n", sizeof(str1));
```

it gives me the size 8 (bytes) when I do `sizeof(str1)`, which does not makes sense to me.

When I initialize a random string with

```
char str2[] = "Big";
printf("size of str2: %ld\n", sizeof(str2));
```

it gives me the size 4 (bytes) when I do `sizeof(str2)`, which DOES make sense to me because three chars `'B'`, `'i'`, `'g'`, and `'\0'`.

How come the first one gives me the size 8?

Comment: J - while I didn't downvote, I can surmise the reason is because this is a fairly basic question easily answerable with minimal effort either searching S.O. or the web in general. Don't worry, it isn't the end of the world. But, going forward, make sure you exercise reasonable effort before asking a question if you want to avoid further downvotes. S.O. is here to help, but it shouldn't be used to avoid basic reading or learning. Good luck and welcome to S.O.

Comment: David - Thank you, I will try harder to find things on my own next time. I am very new to here and I didn't even know I was downvoted...haha. Sorry everyone.

Comment: Don't worry about the downvote, we have all had our share. This is a fantastic site, and we all do our part to make it as useful as possible. The vote/reputation system just adds a bit of ... integrity ... to the site. Again, welcome aboard.

Comment: Thank you sir! It really is a fantastic site! Lots to learn out here.

Comment: An array and a pointer are different types!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, when using `sizeof` on a pointer, it gives you the size of the *datatype*, i.e, the pointer itself, not the size of the *allocated or pointed* memory location.

So, in case of

```
char *str1 = "Big";
```

`sizeof(str1)` will give you the size of `str1` itself, i.e, the size of `char *`. This will vary depending on your platform and compiler used, like for 32-bit, it will be 4 and for 64-bit, it will be 8, *usually*.

Then,

```
 char str2 = "Big";
```

is *invalid*. If you meant

```
 char str2[] = "Big";
```

in that case, `str2` is an *array*, initialized by the supplied string and the null terminator. So, the total size will be `4 * sizeof(char)` which is 4.

Comment: oh, yes I meant str2[]. I see! So the size of a pointer is 8 bytes? Thank you!

Comment: But be aware, the `sizeof (a pointer)` is not always `8`. For instance on `x86` the size is `4`. So it is dependent on the architecture.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
char *str1 = "Big";
```

`str1` is a char pointer. Generally `sizeof( pointer )` is fixed size, and machine-dependent. So `sizeof( char* ) = sizeof( int* ) = sizeof( any pointer )` is usually 4 Bytes (32-bit machine) or 8 Bytes (64-bit machine). There can be some [exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751749/size-of-a-pointer/6751914#6751914) though.

```
char str2[] = "Big";
```

`str2` a character array with terminator '\0' at the end, thus `sizeof( str2 ) = 4`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, so is it because my system is 64 bit, giving me 8 btyes? cool! And I meant str2[], sorry!

Comment: Pointers could be any size (and pointers to different types may have different sizes on the same machine), it's best not to make any assumptions

Comment: I see, I will stop making any assumptions on that. Thank you!

Comment: @M.M - thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

**str1** is a pointer, Any pointer(int, char, float) size must be **4 byte** or **8 byte** depending on the machine.

`sizeof()` is used to get the actual size of any type of data in bytes.

Besides, sizeof() is a compile-time expression giving you the size of a type or a variable's type. It doesn't care about the value of the variable.

Also, a **sizeof()** will give different results for the different declarations.

The second one **str2**, the array declaration, will return the length of the array including the terminating null character.

Comment: Pointers could be any size, it's best not to make any assumptions