# simple string copy, but memcpy doesn't work

Tags: c, malloc, memcpy

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{
    unsigned char str[] = "abcdefg";
    unsigned char *str1 = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(str) -1);

    memcpy(str1, str, (sizeof(str)-1) );

    for(int i = 0; i<(sizeof(str1)); i++)
        printf("%c", str1[i]);

    free(str1);
}
```

I want copy the string `str` to `str1` but the output is

> abcd

It means that only pointer byte(4byte) is copied.

And i try

```
printf("%d", sizeof(str)-1 );
```

it's output is `7`

What is my mistake?

Comment: `str1` is a pointer. Its size is 4.

Comment: @tkausl how can i use str1 space that i claimed malloc on memcpy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it mean that only pointer byte(4byte) is copied.

No, it does not. You're assuming that your printout is correct, which it is not. You can use `sizeof` on arrays but not on pointers. Well, you can, but it means something different.

Everything is copied. You're just printing the first four characters. Change to:

```
for(int i = 0; i<(sizeof(str) - 1); i++)
```

Also, don't cast malloc. Here is why: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/6699433)

Answer (score 1):

`str1` is a pointer whereas `str` is a character array. When you say `sizeof(str1)` in your `for` loop, it iterates 4 times because `sizeof(str1)` must have evaluated to `4`(a 32 bit compiler) whereas `sizeof(str)` evaluates to the correct length.

You should read [What is the size of a pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751749/what-is-the-size-of-a-pointer) once to know more about size of pointers.

Fixed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{
    unsigned char str[] = "abcdefg";
    unsigned char *str1 = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(str) -1);

    memcpy(str1, str, (sizeof(str)-1) );

    for(int i = 0; i<(sizeof(str) - 1); i++)
        printf("%c", str1[i]);

    free(str1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First the mistakes and then the correct code:
Mistakes:

1. Don't ever use `sizeof(str)` to get the length of the string. It doesn't work with pointers. Instead, use `strlen(str) + 1`.
2. You are subtracting 1 from the size of the string on `malloc` call. Why? You are not making space for the ending NULL character.
3. When copying strings, if you know that the destination string is large enough to store the source, use `strcpy` instead of `memcpy`. If you only want an additional size parameter like in `memcpy`, use `strncpy`. `memcpy` is not meant to deal with strings, but with plain arrays.
4. The correct type to use for strings is `char`, not `unsigned char`.
5. Not really a mistake, but to print a string you can use `printf("%s", str)` or `puts(str)`. Why bother with a for loop?
6. `void main()` is prohibited by the C standard.

Correct code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char str[] = "abcdefg";
    char str1* = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);
    strcpy(str1, str);
    puts(str1);
    free(str1);
    //return 0; - default in C99 and later
}
```

Comment: str is not a pointer.

Comment: @n.m. still bad practice. Btw he did `sizeof(str1)` in his question. Look at his for loop.

Comment: No mistake made by OP justifies saying that str is a pointer. `sizeof(str)` returns tge correctvsize of str array. Whether it is a good practice or not is a different question. You cannot discuss good and bad practices based on distorted facts.

Comment: @n.m. Please use some punctuation marks, man. I cannot understand anything of what you said.