# Segmentation fault when writing to array of strings

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am trying to copy some of the arguments passed in argv to an array of strings. Here is my program.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (int argc, char * argv[]) {
    char **args = malloc(argc * sizeof(char *));
    for (int i = 0; i < argc - 1; ++i) {
        strcpy(*(args+i), argv[i+1]);
    }
}
```

I am getting a segmentation fault in the for loop. Why is this happening?

Comment: You are only allocating an array of pointers. You need to also allocate every item in the array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get the segmentation fault because you are using uninitialized pointers.

In other words: `*(args+i)` is uninitialized.

Let's look at your memory:

```
char **args = malloc(argc * sizeof(char *));
```

This will give a local variable `args` that points to a dynamic allocated memory area consisting of `argc` pointers to `char`. Looks like this:

[image]

But the `argc` pointers to char are uninitialized (i.e. `malloc` doesn't initialized anything) so the real picture is:

[image]

That is - the `argc` pointers to char may point anywhere.

So when you do

```
strcpy(*(args+i), argv[i+1]);
       ^^^^^^^^^
       Read uninitialized pointer
```

you read the i'th uninitialized pointer and copy the string at `argv[i+1]` to that location. In other words - to a location that we can't know where is and most like doesn't belong to your program. This is likely to result in a seg fault.

So before you copy anything you want those char-pointers to point to some chars. Like:

[image]

So basically you need to do additional `malloc`.

Now one problem is: How many chars do you need to `malloc`?

Well, you can't know until you know the length of the input strings. So you need to put the `malloc` inside the loop. Like:

```
int main (int argc, char * argv[]) {
    char **args = malloc(argc * sizeof(char *));
    for (int i = 0; i < argc - 1; ++i) {
        *(args+i) = malloc(strlen(argv[i+1]) + 1);  // Allocate memory
        strcpy(*(args+i), argv[i+1]);
    }
}
```

Note:

- You don't need to write `sizeof(char)` as it is always 1
- You have to add 1 to the string length of the input string in order to reserve memory for the string termination.
- You should always check that `malloc` doesn't return NULL
- Instead of `*(args+i)` you can use the more readable form `args[i]`

So after a real execution the picture could be:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in this part of your code:

```
malloc(argc * sizeof(char *));
```

Don't think that `sizeof(char*)` would give you the size of a string.

[What is the size of a pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751749/what-is-the-size-of-a-pointer)

**Solution:**

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])

{
    char* copyOfArgv;

    copyOfArgv = strdup(argv[1]);
}
```

[strdup() - what does it do in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252782/strdup-what-does-it-do-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you allocated memory for the pointers not for the string (arguments from `argv` itself) hence the `strcpy` is invalid - causing `segmentation fault`.

It would've been better to just:

Allocate memory for the pointers (as you have done) then make those pointers **point** to the arguments passed. Example:

```
 #include <string.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <unistd.h>

 int main (int argc, char * argv[]) {
     char **args = malloc(argc*sizeof(char *)); //allocated memory for the pointers only
     int i=0;

     for(;i<argc;i++)
     {
         args[i]=argv[i];  //making the pointers POINT to the arguments including the 0th argument as well
         i++;
     }
     return 0;
 }
```

For using `strcpy` you should've allocated memory for the arguments itself and then copied those.

Comment: While this is correct code wise, I don't see the point. If a program doesn't need a real copy of the strings, why make a copy of the pointers? In thus cases the program could simply use `argv` and not copy anything at all.