# Strange GCC (trunk) behaviour using c++20 concept with templated class: Is it a bug or a feature?

Tags: c++, c++20

Recently I was using `concept`s to define different constructors for a `template`d `class`. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <concepts>

template<typename T> concept scalar = std::is_scalar_v<T>;

template<typename T>
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(T t) requires scalar<T>: _t{t} { std::cout << "is scalar" << std::endl; }
    Foo(T t) requires (not scalar<T>): _t{t} { std::cout << "is not scalar" << std::endl;}
private:
    T _t;
};

class cls {};

int main() 
{
    Foo(true);
    Foo('d');
    Foo(3.14159);
    cls c;
    Foo(c);

    return 0;
}
```

[To my surprise the code does not compile using GCC (trunk).](https://godbolt.org/z/2pGQMK)
The first part of the error message reads:

```
error: conflicting declaration 'Foo<...auto...> c'
```

What do you think, is it a bug or a feature?

Comment: Ask on `gcc-help@gcc.gnu.org`

Comment: @Basile No, please don't.

Comment: `Foo(c);` means `Foo c;` I can't find a good dupe, maybe [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45991094/2069064)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like an issue with parenthesis and the expression being a constructor call without anything else (maybe a most vexing parse kind-of situation?).

These compile:

```
auto fc = Foo(c);
Foo{c};
Foo(cls{});
Foo<cls>({});
```