# strcat_s(), debug assertion failed, {L"Buffer is too small" && 0}

Tags: c++

I am having difficulty using the strcat_s() function. Concatinating char strings works find, but trying with char* string will have runtime errors. [As shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kArS2.png)

Here is the code:

```
#include "Mystring.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>   

int main() {
    char* str1 = new char[100];
    char* str2 = new char[10];
    strcpy_s(str1, strlen("Hello") + 1, "Hello");
    std::cout << str1;
    strcpy_s(str2, strlen(" World") + 1, " World");
    std::cout << str2;
    strcat_s(str1, sizeof(str1), str2);
    std::cout << str1;

    char str3[100] = "Hello";
    char str4[10] = " World";
    strcat_s(str3, sizeof(str3), str4);
}
```

I search everywhere for the implementation of strcat_s(), and did everything as instructed but there must be some underline principles that I do not understand.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61842754/sizeof-on-array-variable-vs-sizeof-on-pointer-in-c. You also have an issue with the `strcpy_s` call, although it doesn't cause an error here: The second parameter should be the number of bytes in the destination, not the length of the source.

Comment: Note that the name of the source file is mentioned in the message! I find it at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Source\10.0.22621.0\ucrt\inc\corecrt_internal_string_templates.h`

Comment: Why are you even still using those functions??? In C++ use 'std::strirg`  like this `std::string str1{"hello"};  str2{" world"}; str1 = str1 + str2;`. Certainly if you want to write safe code you snould not be using manual `new`. (You already have a memory leak too)

Comment: Second parameter of `strcpy_s` is the size of buffer (param1) and not the length of copied string. 100 and 10 in your first 2 cases.

Comment: I am very new to programming, and this is just to solve a problem in my assignment (learning how to write my own string class, and add some functionalities). Thank you all for the help

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
strcat_s(str1, sizeof(str1), str2);
```

`sizeof(str1)` is not evaluating to what you think it is.  `str1` is a pointer to the first byte in an array, not the array itself.

So `sizeof(str1)` will evaluate the size of a pointer: either 4 or 8 bytes. That's less than the number of bytes required to hold "Hello World".  That's why it asserts. You're basically invoking it like this:

```
strcat_s(str1, 4, " World");
```

As you have discovered, the quick fix is change this:

```
char* str1 = new char[100];
```

To this:

```
char str1[100];
```

And don't invoke `delete[]` on it since it's no longer being allocated with new.  Then `sizeof()` will work as you might expect.

Or, the more general fix is to always associate a size capacity variable with any given pointer to an array.

Also, while we are here, this is bad form:

```
strcpy_s(str1, strlen("Hello") + 1, "Hello");
```

This doesn't cause a problem with your program, but your second param to `destination` should be the capacity of the destination buffer, not the length of the source string. It just happens to fit in your code.

Better program:

```
int main() {
    const size_t len1 = 100;
    const size_t len2 = 10;
    char* str1 = new char[len1];
    char* str2 = new char[len2];

    strcpy_s(str1, len1, "Hello");
    std::cout << str1;

    strcpy_s(str2, len2, " World");
    std::cout << str2;

    strcat_s(str1, len1, str2);
    std::cout << str1;

    char str3[100] = "Hello";
    char str4[10] = " World";
    strcat_s(str3, sizeof(str3), str4);

    delete [] str1;
    delete [] str2;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I litterally spent 6+ hours trying to work this out