# cast from ‘int*’ to ‘unsigned int’ loses precision error

Tags: c++, c++14

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int temp = 300;

    cout << "Address of variable temp:  " << (unsigned)&temp;
    return 0;
}
```

> main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
> main.cpp:17:57: error: cast from ‘int*’ to ‘unsigned int’ loses precision [-fpermissive]
> cout << "Address of variable temp:  " << (unsigned)&temp;

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the size of a pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751749/what-is-the-size-of-a-pointer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You convert a **pointer** to `int` to an `unsigned int`.

The problem is that an `unsigned int` is too little to contain all possible values of a pointer to `int`.

You can try with an `unsigned long long` that should be great enough

```
(unsigned long long)&temp;
```

You can check the dimension of the type with `sizeof()`, that return the number of bytes of a type/variable

With my platform (Linux amd64) from

```
std::cout << sizeof(&temp) << std::endl;
std::cout << sizeof(unsigned) << std::endl;
```

I get `8` (for `sizeof(&temp)`) and `4` (for `sizeof(long)`).

And, obviously, a 4 bytes variable can't represent all possible values of a 8 bytes variable.

From a different platform you can get different values.

Comment: by the way, I have solved this by using std::intptr_t but your suggestion worked as well, Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure, why you are trying to cast it. But if you are trying to see the memory address of temp then you should do `&temp`.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int temp = 300;

    cout << "Address of variable temp:  " << &temp;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: On possible explanation for casting is that printing of a pointer may result in hexadecimal notation. The OP might find that disagreeable.

Comment: OK, I'll remove my post.

Comment: I don't think removal is necessary. This is a perfectly fine answer.

Comment: I want the output as an integer that's why I have used unsigned keyword,