# How is memory allocated, when using structures

Tags: c, struct

I'm curious, how exactly does memory allocation looks like after calling `struct list x;` for code bellow:

```
struct list {
    int key; 
    char name[10];
    struct list* ptr;
};
```

Variable `x` will store 4 bytes for `key`, 10 bytes for `name` and how much bytes for `ptr`?

Comment: It will most probably be allocated on the stack. It'll be automatically freed when `x` goes out of scope. Do `printf("%uz", sizeof(struct list*));` to see the size of the pointer. It's most likely 4 (on a 32 bit system) or 8 bytes (on a 64 bit system).

Comment: `ptr` will be either 4 or 8 bytes depending on whether you're in 32-bit or 64-bit mode.

Comment: There will also probably be 2 bytes of padding between `name` and `ptr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be dependent on one's architecture but [try it out](https://tio.run/##hZDBDoIwDIbve4oGowGjRs8zvoRHNWbZhizCIFsxUeOzYyEQAQ/stHX/9zWtXMtU2FtVzYyVaak07D0qk2@SA2MeXSkRUuMR3gzoGItw108OzUsmwoEVmT7tthfelHrIEgp0nH04YzWWCWPDR25U1LoKR@U4DI7mpSGPO9R4mKuzDVbg6SOPw54yiv66ACb6Wl/4QPqTCQShlNOevEXjXXRINGRosAlgQ5ERVI8/RdWZEUarmaIo0kJOY@ksbGmZrKq@)

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct list {
    int key; 
    char name[10];
    struct list* ptr;
};

int main(void) {
    printf("Size of struct is %d\n", sizeof(struct list));
    struct list the_list;
    printf("struct is at address %p\n", &the_list);
    printf("key is at address %p\n", &the_list.key);
    printf("name is at address %p\n", &the_list.name);
    printf("ptr is at address %p\n", &the_list.ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

When I ran this I got

```
Size of struct is 24
struct is at address 0x7ffcf32ad210
key is at address 0x7ffcf32ad210
name is at address 0x7ffcf32ad214
ptr is at address 0x7ffcf32ad220
```

showing that of the 24 bytes total, the first 4 bytes were for `key` at the beginning of the memory block, the next 12 for `name`, and then the final 8 were for `ptr`. Notice there were 2 bytes of padding between `name` and `ptr`.

But this may differ on different architectures. As always, best to try things out!

Answer (score 2):

`struct list` will be allocated as a single contiguous block of memory likely containing the following (assuming `sizeof(int) == 4` for this platform and toolchain. I use the word "likely" because some considerations here are actually implementation-defined.

- Four bytes for `key`.
- Ten bytes for `name`.
- Padding bytes to align `ptr` to the expected alignment.
- `sizeof(list*)` bytes for a pointer. On a modern-day desktop computer using a common operating system and ABI (meaning a flat addressing model), I could guess that it's likely to be 4 or 8 bytes for 32-bit and 64-bit systems respectively. In reality, a pointer's size is implementation-defined and depends on a number of factors, as Eric Postpischil adds:

  > ...the C standard permits pointers to be different sizes depending on the types they point to. For example, in old word-addressed computers, some pointers may have only a word number. To address characters, a C implementation had to synthesize byte addresses by adding extra bits to the address and generating extra instructions to manipulate the word data.

The size of the alignment is a bit tricky to figure out since it depends on a combination of the platform (different CPU architectures have different alignment requirements), toolchain/ABI, and any unusual commands/configurations (e.g. `#pragma pack` or equivalent).

If I had to guess with reasonable assumptions but no information, it would be plausible that there are two bytes of padding regardless of whether this was a 32-bit or 64-bit system. Two bytes of padding places the offset of `ptr` at 4+10+2=16, which satisfies both a four-byte and an eight-byte alignment.

Comment: Re “A pointer is typically a memory address, so its size is independent of the type of data being pointed to”: This is not universally true. It is common in modern systems with flat address spaces. However, the C standard permits pointers to be different sizes depending on the types they point to. For example, in old word-addressed computers, some pointers may have only a word number. To address characters, a C implementation had to synthesize byte addresses by adding extra bits to the address and generating extra instructions to manipulate the word-sized data.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks; I'm going to edit to make this distinction/caveat more clear. May I quote your comment directly?

Comment: Sure, be my guest.

Answer (score 0):

The size of a *pointer* is constant. It doesn't depend on the size of the structure it points to.

For additional information on the size of pointers, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751749/what-is-the-size-of-a-pointer)

Comment: The C standard allows pointers in a C implementation to have different sizes depending on their types, although all pointers to structures of any kind must have the same size.

Answer (score 0):

Your structure will start with four bytes for `key` (because `int` is four bytes in your C implementation) and ten bytes for `name`. (The C standard would allow a C implementation to insert padding between `key` and `name`, but  there is no need for it.)

Pointers are commonly four or eight bytes in modern systems, but they can be other sizes. They can even be different sizes in different C implementations on the same system. So `ptr` will likely take four or eight bytes in your C implementation.

Pointers may require alignment, such as requiring four-byte alignment for a four-byte pointer. In this case, there will be two bytes of padding after `name` and before `ptr`. That is because the structure has 14 bytes in `key` and `name`, so, to bring that up to a multiple of four, two bytes of padding are needed. (Again, the C standard allows an implementation to insert more padding, but it is not needed.)