# char **s versus char *s[], when and how to use each one?

Tags: c, pointers, char

If I use char `*s[]`, I can do the following:

```
char *s[] = {"foo", "bar", "foobar", "whatever", "john", "doe"};
```

What is the difference with `**s`? How do I use the `char **s` instead of `char *s[]` in that case?

Example: `int main (int argc, char **argv)` instead of `*argv[]`

Comment: Marcelo, don't forget to mark an answer as accepted if it solved the problem or ask for further clarification.

Answer (score 7):

For function parameters, there is no difference.

Otherwise:

```
char *s[];
```

s is an array of pointer to char. And

```
char **s;
```

s is a pointer to pointer to char.

You use the former if you need an array of pointer to char, and you use the latter if you need a pointer to a pointer to a char.

Answer (score 4):

As function parameters, there is no difference whatsoever. They are equivalent.

```
void f(int** p);
void f(int* p[]);
void f(int* p[42]);
```

These three declarations are equivalent.

As objects, they have different types;

```
char *s[] = {"foo", "bar", "foobar", "whatever", "john, "doe"};
```

`s` is an array of `6` pointers to `char` ***`sizeof(s) == 6*sizeof(void*)`***

```
char **s;
```

`s` is a pointer to pointer to `char`. ***`sizeof(s) == sizeof(void*)`***

Comment: +1 for a concise answer.  Minor nit (it shouldn't make a difference): you should be using `sizeof(char *)` instead of `void *`.

Comment: @tomlogic: I am using `void*` to emphasize that all pointers have the same size and that one is a pointer and the other is an array of pointers (no matter what poiners).

Comment: @Armen: not quite: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241205/are-all-data-pointers-of-the-same-size-in-one-platform.  Still, `char *` and `void *` have the same size and representation.

Answer (score 1):

They create the same data structure. The only difference s that char*s[] automatically mallocates enough memory for `{"foo", "bar", "foobar", "whatever", "john, "doe"}` upon initialization. char **s would only allocate one byte for the pointer then you'd to manually mallocate memory yourself for the each  string in the array.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays and pointers are different things. A pointer can be used to access an element in the array. To be able to initialize an array, you need to declare an array, not a pointer.

To show clearly the difference try this:

```
int[] ia = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
int* ip = ia;

printf("sizeof(ia): %zu, sizeof(ip): %zu", sizeof(ia), sizeof(ip));
```

The first should print the size of the array, the second the size of an int pointer.

The odd thing with C is that when an array is passed as a parameter to a function it decays into a pointer. See more in section 2.3 of http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/c-faq/c-2.html. The reason main accepts `argv**` instead of `argv*[]` is that `argv*[]` is decayed into `argv**` when passed as a function parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Not direct answer to your que but this might help you understand a bit more:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    char *s[] = {"foo", "bar", "foobar", "whatever", "john", "doe"};

    printf("  s[0]: %s \n", s[0]);
    printf("    *s: %s \n", *s);
    printf("  *s+1: %s \n", *s+1);
    printf("*(s+1): %s \n", *(s+1));

return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ gcc -o chararr chararr.c 
$ ./chararr 
  s[0]: foo   
    *s: foo 
  *s+1: oo 
*(s+1): bar
```

Answer (score 0):

From my knowledge, **s is the address of the address of s, where *s[] is the address of array s, I think you would store single values in s, yet in s[] you would store array, and array itself is a pointer. Hope this helps!

Comment: Nah, for the double pointer you could store a single value, but its more likely a block of data or a block of pointers that point to blocks

Comment: I meant it points to the array, not that array is the pointer, my bad on that one.

Answer (score 0):

If you define

```
char **s[] = {"foo", "bar", "foobar", "whatever", "john, "doe"};
```

I think that it's the same like defining tridiensional arrays (char s[10][10][10]), since char *s[] is defining a bidimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

when you use `char *s[] = {"foo", "bar", "foobar", "whatever", "john, "doe"};` the compiler already knows the length of array ie: in this case it knows the its a pointer to pointers of 6 character arrays.

`char**` lacks the length information and thats specifically why main has 2 arguments `{length, pointer to pointer to char} == {argc, arv}`

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon your requirement. If your program doesn't have to modify these strings later you can use

```
char *s[] = {"foo", "bar", "foobar", "whatever", "john", "doe"};
```

These are compiled as string literals in read only section.

Assembly output:

```
        .file   "test.c"
        .section        .rodata
.LC0:
        .string "foo"
.LC1:
        .string "bar"
.LC2:
        .string "foobar"
.LC3:
        .string "whatever"
.LC4:
        .string "john"
.LC5:
        .string "doe"
        .text
```

If you try to modify these strings later in the program you would get a segmentation fault. In that case you have to use `char **s`

Comment: How do I allocate (i.e. 6) words with char **s?