# global variables addresses in C

Tags: c, global-variables

I'm trying to figure out the `C` memory layout of global variables.
Here is the program I used:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int a = 1;
char *b = "moish";
//char b[6] = {'m','o','i','s','h',0};
int c = 3;
int d = 4;
int e = 5;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("location: %p\n",&a);
    printf("location: %p\n", b);
    printf("location: %p\n",&c);
    printf("location: %p\n",&d);
    printf("location: %p\n",&e);
    return 0;
}
```

When I compiled and ran it I got what I expected, assuming a reasonable alignment
in which variable `c` is located at `0x56294fab001c` instead of `0x56294fab001a` etc.

```
location: 0x56294fab0010
location: 0x56294fab0014
location: 0x56294fab001c
location: 0x56294fab0020
location: 0x56294fab0024
```

When I use `char *b = "moish"` I get a totally different address:

```
location: 0x55c676551010
location: 0x55c676350784
location: 0x55c676551014
location: 0x55c676551018
location: 0x55c67655101c
```

Why is that? I thought the 2 options are equivalent, no?

Comment: You use the wrong format specifier`%lx` to print the addresses instead of `%p`. Why do you cast it to fit to `%lx`?

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio changed to `%p` ...

Answer (score 1):

This is an actual array

```
char b[6] = {'m','o','i','s','h',0}; // size is 6 byte
```

While this is just a pointer which points to a read only memory location where was "moish" placed since its a constant string.

```
char *b = "moish"; // size is the char pointer size of the architecture
```

Actually this would be the real equivalent of `char b[6] = {'m','o','i','s','h',0};`

```
char b[] = "moshi"; // or char b[6] = "moshi" , does not matter in this case
```

Comment: `char b[6]` is not on the stack.

Comment: @kiranBiradar Whops, Yes, edited it. Thanks.

Comment: @kiranBiradar So where is it? even if there is not concept of stack in the C standard, for sure `b[6]` is placed on the stack on all implementations

Comment: In the `.data` segment of the executable if it is initialized. If not initialized then its on the `.bss` segment. Local variables stored onto the stack.

Comment: @Eraklon we are talking about `char b[6] = {'m','o','i','s','h',0};`, it seems an array to me (not a string literal)

Comment: @DavidRanieri Thats an array yes. But "moish" is string literal, but more importantly `char *b` is a pointer! While `char b[6]` is an array.

Comment: *"size is the pointer size of the architecture"* - Note that the sizes of pointers may be different between the types they point to on some systems. -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/13112571/12139179

Comment: And that's what I say ;) `b[6]` is an array, in this case (at global scope) it will be placed in the .data segment, that's true, I didn't pay attention to that

Comment: Although the answer that I previously linked is good, I´d wanted to link to that question but couldn´t found it in the time window to edit my comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916051/are-there-any-platforms-where-pointers-to-different-types-have-different-sizes

Answer (score 0):

When you declare

```
int a;
char b[6];
int c;
```

the variable b takes up the space between a and c, which is what you expected.  When you declare

```
int a;
char* b;
int c;
```

and print the addresses of a, b and c, you will get the consecutive addresses as expected BUT you are printing b: not &b.  That prints whatever b is pointing to: not the address of b.  It is printing the location of "moish" which may be in a completely different area.

**Edit**
Just think of it as RAM and ROM.  Anything that can be changed is RAM and anything that cannot be changed is ROM.  If you declare

```
int a;
const char* b = "moish";
const char c[] = "hsiom";
int d;
```

a, b and d will be in RAM, c and "moish" will be in ROM.  Printing &a, &b, &d will result in RAM addresses.  Printing b and c will result in ROM addresses.  Since b is a variable, it is possible to

```
b = c;
```

but not

```
c = b;
```

Comment: when I change the `char b[6] = { ... }` to  `const char b[6] = { ... }` the memory allocation is the same as `char *b = "moish"` ... so I guess it's just a matter of `const`-ness right?