# How dangerous is conversion from void ** to char **

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers

So we know that the standard doesn't force pointer sizes to be equal. ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241205/are-all-data-pointers-of-the-same-size-in-one-platform) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916051/are-there-are-any-platforms-where-pointers-to-different-types-have-different-siz)) (and not talking about function pointers)

I was wondering how in reality that can be an issue. We know that `void *` can hold anything, so if the pointer sizes are different, that would be the biggest size. Given that, assigning a `void **` to a `char **` means trouble.

My question is how dangerous would it be to assume `void *` and `char *` have the same size? Is there actually an architecture where this is not true?

Also, 16-bit dos is not what I want to hear! ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`void *` and `char *` are guaranteed to have the same size.

`void **` is not guaranteed to have the same size as `char **` (but very likey on your implementation they will).

> (C99, 6.2.5p27) "A pointer to void shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as a pointer to   a character type [...] Pointers to other types need not     have the same representation or alignment requirements."

Comment: @DavidCowden what is the question that is left unanswered for you?

Comment: @DavidCowden I didn't edit the question. And if you look at the time I  also didn't edit the answer: your comment is after the 5 min edit time. I don't know what you mean.

Comment: I added the C99 paragraph to illustrate my two lines in the 5 min time frame. And this was done before your inital comment.

Comment: @DavidCowden, this in fact _does_ answer my question. Since `void *` and `char *` have the same size, an array of `void *` can be safely viewed as an array of `char *`, that is the `void **` can be used as `char **`.

Comment: @Shahbaz YES. lol it does now.  The first version of it didn't (=  I don't understand the big uproar..  I was pointing out that the original version of this answer didn't actually discuss `char **` and `void **`.

Comment: @Shahbaz: an array of `void *` can't be safely viewed as an array of `char *` because it violates effective typing

Comment: @Christoph, by array, I meant a continuous list of elements, like what you get with `malloc`. Not the type with `[]`.

Comment: @Shahbaz: same problem - allocated memory has an effective type defined by the last store, and access via an expression of incompatible type is UB; any memory location has an effective type and may only be accessed through an expression of that type, a compatible one or `char`; this implies that expressions of incomatible type can't alias, and compilers are free to optimize on that assumption

Comment: @Christoph, what if you cast it to `char **` and never access it through the `void **` again?

Comment: @Shahbaz: that should work as expected; it's still UB, though

Comment: @Christoph, thanks for the help. Could you point me to where in the standard this particular case is discussed?

Comment: @Christoph, thanks. I guess I would have to allocate new memory and assign pointers one by one to make sure all conversions are done according to the standard.

Answer (score 3):

Assigning pointers of different object types to each other is allowed as long as no alignment requirements are violated: The assignment will involve an (implicit) type conversion, so it is as (un)problematic as assigning a `float` to an `int` - it works in most cases but is allowed to blow up when a meaningful conversion is impossible.

`char *` and `void *` have compatible alignment requirements per spec, so assigning a `char **` to a `void **` variable (and vice versa) is never problematic. They even have compatible representation, which means in principle, accessing a `char *` through an expression of type `void *` - eg by dereferening a `void **` which actually points to a `char *` - will work as expected in most cases. Of course, the converse (accessing a `void *` by dereferencing a `char **`) holds true as well.

For example, the `p` conversion specifier for `printf()` expects a `void *` and passing in an arbitrary pointer type is undefined behaviour. However, in case of `char *`, it should work even on exotic architectures (eg with different pointer representations) as long as the implementation conforms to the C standard.

Where problems may arise is aliasing analysis: Due to the effective typing rules, a `void **` and a `char **` can't alias, and if the programmer breaks that promise, strange things may happen. One should realize that because of effective typing (aka strict aliasing), C is actually strongly typed - the type system is just very unsound (ie doesn't protect you from violating its invariants)...

Comment: Could you explain that list part a bit more? Why would aliasing them cause problem? Is that due to optimization? Would two `char **`s aliasing each other be ok, but this not? If so, how is that?

Comment: @Shahbaz: if you have a function with signature `void foo(char **a, void **b)`, then the compiler is free to assume that `a != b` (*this is a gross simplicfication and actually a lie*); if both `a` and `b` had type `char **`, the compiler can't make that assumption, which limits optimization and led to the introduction of `restrict`; note that this has nothing to do with  `a` and `b` being pointer-to-pointers - the same were true if they had type `int *` and `float *`