# Why do I need a reinterpret_cast to convert Fred ** const to void ** const?

Tags: c++, void-pointers, reinterpret-cast, static-cast

I have a const pointer to a pointer to a `Fred` and I don't understand why a `static_cast` isn't sufficient.

```
typedef struct {
    int n;
} Fred;

Fred *pFred;
Fred **const ppFred = &pFred;
void **const ppVoid = static_cast<void ** const>(ppFred);
```

Please could someone explain why a `reinterpret_cast` is needed to convert a pointer to `Fred*`to a pointer to `void*` but `static_cast` is fine to convert pointer to `Fred` to a pointer to `void`.

Comment: does it make sense to have a `void**` at all?

Comment: I'm coding to a C-style call-back messaging style interface and receive a pointer to a struct. The same C call is used to get back all structs so not sure I have many other options.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11409289/c-comparison-of-array-of-pointers, although that was C and the other questioner was also asking how to work around it in their case.

Comment: @moooeeeep A `void**` is a pointer to `void*`, it might to used to "pass by reference" a `void*` to a function in C. `realloc` interface could have been defined that way. I am *not* advocating this idea here, just saying it is a possibility.

Comment: @DangerMouse "`static_cast<void ** const>`" you know this **const** has no purpose or effect, don't you?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's no requirement that a `Fred*` and a `void*` have the same size
and representation.  (I've worked on machines where they didn't,
although that was before my C++ days.)  When you convert `Fred*` to
`void*`, you get a new pointer, with a possibly different size and
representation, but there is no information about the size and
representation of the object the `void*` points to.  You know that it is
unknown, and the only way to use this `void*` is to cast it back to a
`Fred*` (modulo things like cv-qualifiers).  When you convert `Fred**` 
to `void**`, you're converting from a pointer to a concrete type (a
pointer to a `Fred*`) to a pointer to another concrete type (a pointer
to a `void*`).  And since there's no guarantee that these two concrete
types have the same size and representation, the conversion requires a
`reinterpret_cast`.  `void` is a special, non-concrete type, so you can
`static_cast` a pointer to any type to and from a pointer to `void`.
`void*` is just another concrete pointer type, so casting to and from
pointers to it follows the usual rules (and requires a
`reinterpret_cast`).

In many ways, the situation is very much like `int` and `double`, where
`void*` plays the role of `int` (say), and `Fred*` the role of `double`.
There's no problem `static_cast`ing between `int` and `double`, but
casts between `int*` and `double*` require `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: So I could do static_cast<void * const>(&pFred) presumably?

Comment: "void* plays the role of int (say), and Fred* the role of double." - or the other way around, since (typically) every value of `int` is representable as `double`, and (always) every value of `Fred*` is representable as `void*`. The fact that X converts to Y sometimes lulls people into thinking that X* might convert to Y*, I think.

Comment: @SteveJessop Yes.  I didn't consider that aspect when I thought of the example.  It was just the idea that you can convert between two "values", but you couldn't convert between two pointers to those values.

Comment: @DangerMouse Yes, but you can't dereference that pointer.  The only legal way you can dereference it is by casting it back to a `Fred*` (modulo cv-qualifiers), and use that.

Comment: @JamesKanze What's the rationale of exempting conversion to void*? why doesn't that apply to void**?

Comment: @Chethan History, really.  There are still situations where it makes sense to have a pointer to something, without knowing what (although in earliest C, that was `char*`).  It was also agreed that conversions of `T*` to that pointer (now `void*`) could be implicit.  Later, it was decided that the reverse of any implicit conversion should be a `static_cast`.  None of this applies to `void**`, of course, since `void**` doesn't point to just anything; it points to a concrete data type, `void*`.

Comment: @JamesKanze "_the reverse of any implicit conversion_" the reverse of implicit **pointer->pointer** conversions that do not increase cv-qualification.

Comment: @curiousguy Good point.  Cv-qualifications are a separate issue, and you can't use `static_cast` to reduce cv-qualification (at any level).

Answer (score 3):

All object pointers are convertible to `void*`, so a static cast is fine for that. However, converting between `T*` and `U*` in general requires a reinterpret cast, since arbitrary pointers are not mutually convertible. (And substitute `T = Fred*`, `U = void*`.)

Comment: What's the rationale of exempting conversion to void*? why doesn't that apply to void**?

Comment: @Chethan: `void*` is special. Every pointer is convertible to a `void*`.

Answer (score 3):

`static_cast` won't work to convert `Fred **` to `void **` because it's not a sensible conversion : the pointers to `Fred*` and to `void*` are not necessarily created the same way (i.e. alignments problems on some platforms). You can be sure that a `void*` which can point to any byte in memory can point to a `Fred` object as well, but that's not the case for `void**` pointers.

Comment: If I get you, you're saying that a pointer to void* may be a different sort of thing to a pointer to a Fred* but that a pointer to void can point to anything? So I could uses a void* in the function signature just as easily as a void**?

Answer (score 1):

### Disclaimer

**The following is hand-waving** for the purpose of making things easily understood, not a technically correct description.

### The hand-waving

One possible way to introduce `void` is:

`void` is *similar* (not the same thing as) the Java `Object` universal superclass.

`void` can be seen as an abstract base of every class and non-class type. (With this metaphor, `void` would also be a quasi-virtual base type: conversion to `void*` is never ambiguous.)

So you can see the implicit conversion from `T*` to `void*` as a derived-to-base conversion, and the reverse `static_cast` is like a base to derived down-cast. When a `void*` does not really point to a `T`, you should not do a `static_cast<T*>` (when a `Base*` does not really point to a `Derived`, you should not do a `static_cast<Derived*>`).

### Disclaimer, again

**Seriously,** `void` is **not** an abstract base class, and cannot be formally treated as one in many cases:

- You cannot formally describe `void` either as a virtual base (or `static_cast` would break) or a non-virtual base (or conversions to `void*` would be ambiguous when multiple inheritance is used).
- There is no `void&` type. This base class *metaphor* just does extend beyond pointers.

Please, DO NOT go tell people "`void` is the universal C++ base class, like Java Object". *Do not repeat anything I wrote here without the full disclaimers.*

**Only in some cases,** `void` behaves like a base class for the purpose of pointer implicit conversions and casts.

**You cannot write programs based on metaphors,** but on the real C++ rules.

This metaphor might help. Or not. Either way, *do not ever try to draw logical conclusions based on a metaphor.*