# free a cast pointer

Tags: c

I want to know if it is ok to free() a pointer cast to another type.
For instance if I do this:

```
char *p = malloc (sizeof (int));
int *q = (int *)p;
free (q);
```

I get no warning on gcc (-Wall).

On linux, the man pages on free says it is illegal to call free on a pointer that was not returned by malloc(), calloc() or realloc(). But what happens if the pointer was cast to another type in between?

I ask this because I read that the C standard does not require different pointer types (e.g. int* and char*) to have the same size, and I fail to understand how this is possible since they both need to be convertible to a void* in order to call the malloc/free functions.

Is the above code legal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's *probably* safe, but it's not absolutely *guaranteed* to be safe.

On most modern systems, all pointers (at least all object pointers) have the same representation, and converting from one pointer type to another just reinterprets the bits that make up the representation. But the C standard doesn't guarantee this.

```
char *p = malloc (sizeof (int));
```

This gives you a `char*` pointer to `sizeof (int)` bytes of data (assuming `malloc()` succeeds.)

```
int *q = (int *)p;
```

This converts the `char*` pointer to an `int*` pointer.  Since `int` is bigger than `char`, an `int*` pointer *could* require less information to indicate what it points to. For example, on a word-oriented machine, an `int*` might point just point to a word, while a `char*` has to contain a word pointer and an offset that indicates which byte within the word it points to. (I've actually worked on a system, the Cray T90, that worked like this.) So a conversion from `char*` to `int*` can actually lose information.

```
free (q);
```

Since `free()` takes an argument of type `void*`, the argument `q` is implicitly converted from `int*` to `void*`. There is no guarantee in the language standard that converting a `char*` pointer to `int*`,  and then converting the result to `void*`, gives you the same result as converting a `char*` directly to a `void*`.

On the other hand, since `malloc()` always returns a pointer that's correctly aligned to point to any type, even on a system where `int*` and `char*` have different representations, it's unlikely to cause problems in this particular case.

So your code is practically certain to work correctly on any system you're likely to be using, and very very likely to work correctly even on exotic systems you've probably never seen.

Still, I advise writing code that you can *easily* demonstrate is correct, by saving the original pointer value (of type `char*`) and passing it to `free()`. If it takes several paragraphs of text to demonstrate that your code is *almost* certainly safe, simplifying your assumptions is likely to save you effort in the long run. If something else goes wrong in your program (trust me, something will), it's good to have one less possible source of error to worry about.

A bigger potential problem with your code is that you don't check whether `malloc()` succeeded. You don't do anything that would fail if it doesn't (both the conversion and the `free()` call are ok with null pointers), but if you refer to the memory you allocated you could be in trouble.

**UPDATE:**

You asked whether your code is legal; you didn't ask whether it's the best way to do what you're doing.

`malloc()` returns a `void*` result, which can be implicitly converted to any pointer-to-object type by an assignment. `free()` takes a `void*` argument; any pointer-to-object type argument that you pass to it will be implicitly converted to `void*`. This round-trip conversion (`void*` to `something_else*` to `void*`) is safe. Unless you're doing some kind of type-punning (interpreting the same chunk of data as two different types), there's no need for any casts.

Rather than:

```
char *p = malloc (sizeof (int));
int *q = (int *)p;
free (q);
```

you can just write:

```
int *p = malloc(sizeof *p);
...
free(p);
```

Note the use of `sizeof *p` in the argument to `malloc()`. This gives you the size of whatever `p` points to without having to refer to its type explicitly. It avoids the problem of accidentally using the wrong type:

```
double *oops = malloc(sizeof (int));
```

which the compiler likely won't warn you about.

Comment: Thanks for your reply (I don't check malloc() return value only because I wanted a small example). Suppose I have a void* pointer that I allocate "as" an int* or double* (and I always cast it to the correct type before actually dereferencing it), I can free it as a void* pointer when I'm done, without having to cast it to its actual type?

Comment: @NicolasGrebille: This: `double *ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr); ... free(ptr);` is safe, and is the best way to do this. Unless you're doing something very strange, you should never need to cast pointers used with `malloc()` and `free()`; the *implicit* conversions will do exactly what you need.

Comment: Yes, but if I have a void* pointer in a struct that could be allocated "as" a double* or int*, I need to do the casts myself.

Comment: @NicolasGrebille: Yes, there are cases where you actually declare an object (a struct member, for example) as `void*` and can use it to point to different types. But conversions between `void*` and other pointer types don't require casts; just assign the value and the conversion is implicit.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, a cast of any pointer type to/from void* is guaranteed not to loose information, but this is not the case with other pointer types? I mean, with your Cray T90 example, it is not the same to cast from a char* to an int*, and to cast from a char* to a void* to an int*?

Answer (score 3):

Yes the pointer is not changed, the cast is merely how the compiler interprets the bunch of bits.

edit: The malloc call returns an address in memory ie a 32(or 64) bit number.
The cast only tells the compiler how to interpret the value stored at that address, is it a float, integer, string etc, and when you do arithmatic on the address how big a unit should it step in.

Comment: Are you sure? Is there any guarantee that `(void*)((int*)p)` is the same as `(void*)p` for any `p`? As far as I know, the only guarantee is that you can convert a `T *` to a `void *` and back and get the same pointer, but that isn't saying anything about the *value* of the other side.

Comment: @KerrekSB why wouldn't it be different? We're not even doing pointer arithmetic here.

Comment: @H2CO3: Why wouldn't it be different? That's exactly my question.

Comment: You mean that as long as I don't dereference or increment the pointer, the cast could be compiled to a no-op? What I don't understand is how it could be legal to a void* and not to any other pointer type. If I cast a int* to a void*, then to a char* and then to a void*, and then to an int* back, is all of this legal? I don't understand how this could be possible if all pointer types are not the same in the implementation

Comment: The malloc gives an address in memory, ie a 32bit number. You can tell the compiler that the value stored there is a float/int/string etc. But it doesn't change the address - just how arithmatic on the address works

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought, but I learnt here that this is not always true: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241205/are-all-data-pointers-of-the-same-size-in-one-platform. So what if char* and int* have not the same representation?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's legal. `free()` takes a void pointer (`void*`), so the type doesn't matter. As long as the pointer passed to was returned by `malloc/realloc/calloc` it's valid.

Answer (score 0):

The code is legal, however it is not necessary.  Since pointers only point to the address where data is stored, there is no need to allocate space, or subsequently free it.

Comment: I suspect the poster is writing a minimum example rather than malloc-ing a single int