# better understanding type promotion of variadic parameters in c

Tags: c, floating-point, int, printf, c99

When a variable argument function is called in c the integer parameters are promoted to int and floating point parameters are promoted to double

> Since the prototype doesn’t specify types for optional arguments, in a call to a variadic function the *default argument promotions* are performed on the optional argument values. This means the objects of type `char` or `short int` (whether signed or not) are promoted to either `int` or `unsigned int`, as appropriate; and that objects of type `float` are promoted to type `double`. So, if the caller passes a `char` as an optional argument, it is promoted to an `int`, and the function can access it with `va_arg (ap, int)`.

`int` type should be 4 byte on 32 bit machines and 8 byte on 64 bit machines, is that right?
So I wonder what append when I pass a `long long int` to a variable argument function like printf with `%lld` format.
And, again, I wonder what append when I pass a `long double` variable to printf with `%Lf` format (no matter if on 32 or 64 bit machines).

[**Edited**]

on a 32 bit machine, I tried this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("sizeof(int) %d\n", sizeof(int));
    printf("sizeof(long int) %d\n", sizeof(long int));
    printf("sizeof(long long int) %d\n", sizeof(long long int));
    printf("%lld\n", 1LL<<33);

    printf("sizeof(float) %d\n", sizeof(float));
    printf("sizeof(double) %d\n", sizeof(double));
    printf("sizeof(long double) %d\n", sizeof(long double));
    return 0;
}
```

The result is:

```
sizeof(int) 4
sizeof(long int) 4
sizeof(long long int) 8
8589934592
sizeof(float) 4
sizeof(double) 8
sizeof(long double) 12
```

this makes me think that not all parameters are promoted to `int`, otherwise I would get printed 0 instead of 8589934592.

Maybe only arguments smaller than `int` are promoted to `int`. And something similar could be for floating point types.

[**Edited**]

on a 64 bit machine I run this:

```
int main(void)
{
    printf("sizeof(int) %lu\n", sizeof(int));
    printf("sizeof(long) %lu\n", sizeof(long));
    printf("sizeof(long long) %lu\n", sizeof(long long));
    return 0;
}
```

and get

```
sizeof(int) 4
sizeof(long) 8
sizeof(long long) 8
```

if I understand well the standard, only `char` and `short` are promoted to `int`. I wonder what happen in smaller architecture, such like 16 bit or 8 bit MCU. I think that `int` size is dependent by architecture, but I wonder if `sizeof(int)` can be 1 on 8 bit architecture. In this case promotion of `short` to `int` could be impossible unless loosing some bits

Comment: `int` must be _at least_ 16 bits, but no further guarantee is made by the Standard.

Comment: and `long long` must be at least 64 bit per C99

Comment: [An `int` must be able to contain a `short`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p8). Also, the Standard specifies that an [`int` must be at least 16 bits](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.4.2.1), regardless of underlying architecture. `_Bool` is also promoted to `int`.

Comment: To add-- It is entirely possible for `short` to be the same size as `int`, or for `int` to be the same size as `long`. It is also possible to have 16 bit `char`s, in which case it would be possible to also have 16 bit `int`s, and `sizeof (int) == 1`. These are implementation details, not dependent on architecture.

Comment: Your programs all have undefined behaviour due to using the wrong format specifier for `size_t`. (should be `%zu`)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

"`int` type should be 4 byte on 32 bit machines and 8 byte on 64 bit machines, is that right?" No. According to the Standard, [`int`s must be *at least* 16 bits in width (§5.2.4.2.1)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.4.2.1), but there is no further stipulation.

When you pass a `long long int` to `printf()` it is not subject to [the integer promotions (§6.3.1.1 2)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.1p2):

> The following may be used in an expression wherever an int or unsigned
>   int may be used:
>
> - An object or expression with an integer type (other than int or unsigned int) whose integer conversion rank is less than or equal to
>     the rank of int and unsigned int.
> - A bit-field of type _Bool, int, signed int, or unsigned int.
>
> If an int can represent all values of the original type (as restricted
>   by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to an int;
>   otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int. These are called the
>   integer promotions.58) **All other types are unchanged by the integer
>   promotions**.

If you pass a `long double` to `printf()` [no conversion is made (§6.5.2.2 6)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.2p6):

> If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that
>   does not include a prototype, the integer promotions are performed on
>   each argument, and arguments that have type float are promoted to
>   double. These are called the default argument promotions.

The conversion specifiers corresponding to the arguments in the `printf()` statement have no bearing on these promotions and conversions, except insofar as there will be undefined behavior if the specifiers and the types of their corresponding arguments do not match.

So, the integer promotions are performed, and `float`s are converted to `double`s, but ["No other conversions are performed implicitly" (§6.5.2.2 8)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.2p8).

Addressing your edit to the question: "this makes me think that not all parameters are promoted to `int`." Correct. Only integer types with integer conversion rank "less than or equal to the rank of `int` and `unsigned int`" are subject to integer promotion. It is simpler for floating point types; `float`s are promoted to `double`. That is all.

It may be worth pointing out that, according to [§6.2.5 10](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p10), there are three real floating point types, `float`, `double`, and `long double`. The values which may be held by a `float` are a subset of the values which may be held by a `double`, which are in turn a subset of the values which may be held by a `long double`. Hence, there is no possibility of promotion for `long double` types.

Further, according to [§6.3.1.1 1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.1p1):

> The rank of long long int shall be greater than the rank of long int,
>   which shall be greater than the rank of int, which shall be greater
>   than the rank of short int, which shall be greater than the rank of
>   signed char.

So there is no possibility of a `long long int` or `long int` ever being promoted to `int` or `unsigned int`.

As for your final concern that promotion of a `short` to an `int` may, in some implementation, be impossible without losing some bits, note that [§6.2.5 8](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p8) guarantees that an `int` must be able to contain a `short`, since the conversion rank of an `int` must be greater than that of a `short`:

> For any two integer types with the same signedness and different
>   integer conversion rank (see 6.3.1.1), the range of values of the type
>   with smaller integer conversion rank is a subrange of the values of
>   the other type.

Comment: I talk about printf only for example. I wonder, if I write my varidic function, that I pass to it are all converted to int or only smaller? I edited original post to explain

Comment: @mastupristi-- the rules for promotion are the same for any variadic function.

Comment: @David-- for floating point types should be the same: `float` are promoted to `double`, and no conversion for `long double`. I added some other stuff

Comment: @mastupristi-- What am I missing? Isn't that what I said: "`floats` are promoted to `double`. That is all." Or, previously, "The integer promotions are performed, and `float`s are converted to `double`s, but 'No other conversions are performed implicitly'."

Comment: @David-- yes, you are right. my comment was only for sake of precision

Comment: @mastupristi-- I added some comments about conversion rank and relative type sizes. Maybe this will help to clarify.

Comment: I added some consideration about 16 and 8 bit machines. Also added a test on 64 bit

Comment: Minor:  "If you pass a long double to printf() with a %Lf conversion specifier, no conversion is made:" --> the "with a %Lf conversion specifier" is not needed.  I point this out as learners sometimes incorrectly think the format string somehow affects the arguments passed.

Answer (score 3):

> int type should be 4 byte on 32 bit machines and 8 byte on 64 bit machines, is that right?

Probably not. First of all, C makes no guarantees about the size of `int`, apart from stating that it *must* be at least 2 bytes (capable of at least holding the value 2^16/2 - 1 = 32767). Nothing in C prevents `int` from being 8 bytes, but that's not very convenient.

The convention is: all 8- and 16 bit computers use 16 bit `int`. All other computers use 32 bit `int`. This is industry de facto standard. Any deviations from this convention would be very exotic, although in theory allowed by C.

---

> So I wonder what append when I pass a long long int to a variable argument function like printf with %lld format.

You get a long long int. No promotion takes place, because the variable is not one of the mentioned small types. The format specifier used is irrelevant to the promotion rules.

---

> this makes me think that not all parameters are promoted to int

Indeed. Only the types that the standard mentions are promoted. The formal definition of the default argument promotions can be found in C11 6.5.2.2/6:

> ...the integer promotions are performed on each argument, and
>   arguments that have type float are promoted to double. These are
>   called the default argument promotions.

Meaning that only the small integer types (see the integer promotion rule) and `float` gets promoted. No other types.

---

Why you think that your examples printing various type sizes have any relevance in relation to the default argument promotions, I have no idea.

Comment: UV for "The format specifier used is irrelevant to the promotion rules."

Answer (score 1):

> So I wonder what append when I pass a `long long int` to a variable
>   argument function like printf with `%lld` format. And, again, I wonder
>   what append when I pass a `long double` variable to printf with `%Lf`
>   format (no matter if on 32 or 64 bit machines).

Nothing happens, as the `long long int` has to be at least of the same size as `int`. Even in the most "pesimistic" scenario, where `sizeof(long long int) == sizeof(int)`, the argument is still passed "as is" (without any promotion). The same applies to `long double`.