# Why I have to use %u with unsigned int and I can use %i with unsigned char?

Tags: c, types

I tried to play with data types in C. My first problem was printf() show negative value with unsigned int. I fixed this with %u instead of %i.

But unsigned char still works with %i, how it is possible?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned int a;
    unsigned char b;

    a = -7;
    b = -1

    printf("a=%u\nb=%i\n", a, b);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Most printable char values are below 127 anyway, so you're probably not going to see any negative values.  That last bit (values 128 and above) is what would encode a negative value.

Comment: And %i has a greater range (32 bits) than a byte, so you're never going to kick over that sign bit anyway.

Comment: Fyi, you're probably going to find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44421125/better-understanding-type-promotion-of-variadic-parameters-in-c/44421610) an interesting read

Comment: Another way of saying: **Avoid undefined behavior at best!**... Can you guess what will happen when you use a bigger datatype with a smaller mode, *e.g,* using `double` with `%f` (***Note:** does not apply to `scanf()`*)...?

Answer (score 1):

If you see e.g. [this `printf` (and family) reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) you will see that the `"%i"` format do

> converts a **signed integer** into decimal representation `[-]dddd`.

<sub>[Emphasis *not* mine]</sub>

Since you pass an `unsigned int` you're having mismatched format specifier and value, which leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Furthermore, for variable argument functions (like `printf`) arguments smaller than `int` (like for example `char`, signed or unsigned) are [*promoted*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions) to `int`. And again, since the resulting value is an `int` (which is signed) and you use the `"%u"` format, there is a mismatch between format specifier and argument type.

Answer (score 0):

As it has been stated before, using 'i' as the format specifier is not correct for a variable of type **unsigned** char.

Whenever you are unsure of what the correct format would be for any particular (integer) type, you can just take a look at inttypes.h, which contains a bunch of macros meant to be used for portable format strings. Depending on the platform you're developing for, the correct format specifiers might differ (uint16_t could be 'u' or 'hu', int32_t could be 'd' or 'ld' for instance).

You could either use this header as a "cheat sheet", or actually write your format strings like this:

```
printf("a=%"PRIu32"\nb=%"PRIu8"\n", a, b);
```

Note that for the code to actually be portable, you would of course also need to use uint8_t instead of unsigned char, and uint32_t instead of int.