# Incorrect passing of uint64_t to va_list

Tags: c, variadic-functions, int64

I am writing a custom `printf` function and a `uint64_t` seems to be passed incorrectly to `va_list`:

Problematic point:

```c
printf("Number is %C, and the next one is %C", 0xff00ffb7, 0xffffffff);
```

Part of my `printf` implementation that produces the incorrect result:

```c
format++;
uint64_t num = va_arg(parameters, uint64_t);
```

When debugging with gdb the value of `num` becomes `0xffffffffff00ffb7` rather than `0xff00ffb7` which I expect, and for the next `%C` `num` becomes 0. Is this some standard behavior I'm missing or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `0xff00ffb7` is an `int` literal. If you want to pass it as an `uint64_t` then cast it to an `uint64_t`.

Comment: Or as `0xff00ffb7ULL`

Comment: @dxiv is there a specific reason it won't get upgraded to a `uint64_t`?

Comment: @frogstair That works the other way around. It has no specific reason to be taken as anything else than an `int` literal, as you wrote it.

Comment: Possibly relevant is: [better understanding type promotion of variadic parameters in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44421125/better-understanding-type-promotion-of-variadic-parameters-in-c)

Comment: @dxiv `0xff00ffb7` is an `unsigned` constant when `unsigned` is 32-bit.  C does not define `int` literal.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Right, I meant int-sized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `0xff00ffb7` is meant to be a `uint64_t` for a variadic function, cast it.

```
printf("Number is %C", (uint64_t) 0xff00ffb7);
```

---

`0xff00ffb7`, as an integer constant, has the type of `int, unsigned, long, unsigned long, long long` or , `unsigned long long`: the first one it "fits".  With 32-bit `int/unsigned`, `0xff00ffb7` would be `unsigned` and likely the source of OP's trouble.

Appending `u` to a constant is a *good* idea to insure it is some unsigned type.

Appending `L` or `LL` to a constant is not a good idea to insure a constant is `uint64_t`.  Either *might* match (`LL` often will), but these suffixes do not guarantee that type.

Using `UINT64_C(0xff00ffb7)` forms a constant of type `uint_least64_t` which is certainly same as `uint64_t` on machines that have `uint64_t`.