# Why is a pointer cast as (void*)p when used in printf?

Tags: c

```
char  x = 'G';
char *p = &x;

printf ("Address of x: %p\n", p);
printf ("Address of x: %p\n", (void*)p);
```

Can someone tell me what exactly `(void*)p` means? I know that it is the same as `p`, as that also gives me the address of `x`, but why is this written as `(void*)p`?

Comment: The `%p` specifier requires `void*` to be passed as parameter. `(void*)p` is casting `p` to such.

Comment: Well, I don't think that one is a duplicate. This one is more about casting.

Comment: All of these downvotes are stupid: Kai is asking a legimate question.  I'm just not sure if the question is "Q: What's a void *"?, or "Q: Why should I cast to (vooid *) here?"  REFERENCES: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692564/, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24867814/

Comment: @paulsm4 I am afraid pure title contributed. I have edited the title (and retracted the downvote). I, for one, had no idea %p requires void pointer.

Comment: Thank you, Suma.  Another potential duplicate is: [printf("%p") and casting to (void \*)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24867814/printfp-and-casting-to-void)

Comment: The function `printf` is defined something like `int printf(const char *, ...)`. I don't remember there being a `print` function so I'll assume it's a function with the prototype `int print(const char*, void*)`. The `...` accepts anything. The `void*` requires a `void*` hence the cast

Comment: On the machine I learned to program C with (back in the days when the C standard was not yet a gleam in the eye — and before  `void *` or `%p` existed), if you printed `short s; printf("0x%lX\n", &s); printf("0x%lX\n", (char *)&s);`, you would get different results because the machine used word oriented addressing. The same was true for any 'wider than `char`' type compared to the `char *` address for the same object. This meant you had to be excruciatingly careful to ensure that `malloc()` was declared before you used it, as otherwise everything blew up horribly. These days, it is easier.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Any thoughts of C requiring `char *` and `void *` to be passed the same to `...` as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54598093/why-is-pointer-casted-as-void-p-when-used-in-printf#comment95992755_54598134)?

Comment: @chux: C11 [§6.2.5 Types ¶28](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p28) says: _A pointer to void shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as a pointer to a character type.48)_ and footnote 48 says: _The same representation and alignment requirements are meant to imply interchangeability as arguments to functions, return values from functions, and members of unions._  I think they're required to be equivalent in all contexts, including `...` — but simply writing `0` in a `...` portion of an argument list does not necessarily create a pointer-sized value; use a cast.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes the footnote is the clue I've missed.  About 0, related is why `print ("%p" , NULL); print ("%d" , NULL); print ("%ld" , NULL);` are problems vs `print ("%p %d" , (void*) NULL, (int) NULL);`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler When making the `...` vs. `void*` comment, I was thinking more about the warnings that the compiler might give.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The C standard says this about the `%p` format specifier for `printf` family functions (§ 7.21.6.2, paragraph 12)

> The corresponding argument shall be a pointer to a pointer to void.

Pointers to different types may differ in their internal representation, except for `void *` and `char *` pointers, which are guaranteed to be the same size. However, any object pointer type is convertible to `void *`. So, to be sure that all `%p` variables are processed correctly by `printf`, they are required to be `void *`.

Comment: Re “except for”: All pointers to structure types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as each other (but may be different from `void *` and `char *`), per C 2018 6.2.5 28. And union pointers are the same as each other. And pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types are the same as each other.