# Difference between & address and pointer address- Hexadecimal and pointer type data

Tags: c, pointers, integer, printf, conversion-specifier

I am using the following piece of code as a learning exercise for pointers:

```
int a=8;

int *ptr=&a;

printf("\nThe & address of a is: %x\n",&a);
printf("\nThe value of the pointer ptr is: %p \n",ptr);
```

I am doing this to identify the address values given by `&a` and `ptr` and I am noticing the following difference in the output:

```
The & address of a is: a6bff9c4

The value of the pointer ptr is: 000000f5a6bff9c4
```

I can see that the `ptr` value is the `&` value with `000000f5` appended in the beginning. I know that `%x` outputs the `&` address value in hexadecimal. What is the format of the pointer value and how is it different from the hexadecimal `&` value?

Trying to understand the difference between the memory addresses outputted by `&` and pointer variable and understanding their formats.

Comment: The first example is incorrect: `%x` is for type `unsigned int`. In this case your 64-bit pointer was truncated to 32 bits, but the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: Format specifier `%p` requires an argument of type `void*`, not `int*`. There is no automatic conversion for variadic functions. You need to cast the value explicitely.

Comment: To add to what @WeatherVane said, you can prevent that truncation if you use `%x` (for a long unsigned int), you'll see that the results are now the same (except for the `0x` prefix in the `%p`, but that's just a stylistic difference)

Comment: @Alexander did you mean `%llx` for `unsigned long long`? It's still undefined behaviour though.

Comment: @Alexander There is no `0x` prefix for both format specifiers.

Comment: @Gerhardh I'm getting `The value of the pointer ptr is: 0x16d71b38c` on my machine (macOS 13.3).

Comment: @Alexander interesting. I see that is implementation defined. In the output of the OP you can see that there is no `0x`

Comment: Hi everyone, I now understand that the value is being modified according to the format provided. For %x, I am getting e25ffd04. For %llx, I am getting ee25ffd04. For %p, I am getting 0000000ee25ffd04

Comment: Hi @Gerhardh, can you please help me understand by explaining a bit more why casting to (void *) is required? Because with or without casting the same output is displayed

Comment: Getting an expected result does not mean that you can rely on that. The C standard demands that the argument passed is of type `void *`. If you provide any other type (also any other pointer type) you cannot rely on that value having the same representation as a `void*` even if they point to the same address. If you have a function with `void*` in the parameter list and you provide a different pointer, the compiler will automatically convert it because that are the rules for `void*`. But as `printf` does ont have a type for its parameters, that automatic conversion is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conversion specification `%x` expects an object of the type `unsigned int`. `sizeof( unsigned int )` usually is equal to `4`. While `sizeof( int * )` is equal to `4` or `8` bytes depending on the used system.

Using invalid conversion specification results in undefined behavior.

From the C Standard (7.21.6.1 The fprintf function)

> 9 If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is
> undefined.275) If any argument is not the correct type for the
> corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

Instead of this call where with a pointer there is used the conversion specification `%x`

```
printf("\nThe & address of a is: %x\n",&a);
```

you should write

```
#include <inttypes.h>

//...

printf("\nThe & address of a is: %08" PRIXPTR "\n", ( uintptr_t ) ( void * )&a);
```

you need to write

And in the second call of `printf` you need to convert the pointer to the type `void *`.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main( void )
{
    int a = 8; 

    int *ptr = &a;

    printf( "\nThe & address of a is: %08" PRIXPTR "\n", ( uintptr_t )( void * )&a );
    printf( "\nThe value of the pointer ptr is: %p \n", ( void * )ptr );
}
```

The program output might look like

```
he & address of a is: 0116F9BC

The value of the pointer ptr is: 0116F9BC
```

This call of `printf`

```
printf( "\nThe & address of a is: %08" PRIXPTR "\n", ( uintptr_t )( void * )&a );
```

can be more flexible if to rewrite it the following way

```
printf( "\nThe & address of a is: %0*" PRIXPTR "\n", 2 * ( int )( sizeof( &a ) ), ( uintptr_t )( void * )&a );
```

Answer (score 4):

Using the `%x` format specifier truncates part of the data you are attempting to display.  `%x` is essentially designed to format an `int` in its hexadecimal form, typically with room for 4 bytes, but being asked to represent a pointer that in this case (but not always) occupies more space than an `int`

The `%p` format specifier is specifically designed to accommodate depictions of pointers.  Depending on the addressing of the system the pointer is referencing, it will be either 4 bytes (32bit) or 8 bytes (64bit)

Thus `a6bff9c4` is erroneously depicted with `%x`, and should be depicted using `%p`.

Comment: @NeuronB - Referring to your question regarding why cast "%p" arguments to void *, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54598093/why-is-a-pointer-cast-as-voidp-when-used-in-printf/54598134#54598134), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11629682/645128), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54598093/why-is-a-pointer-cast-as-voidp-when-used-in-printf/54598134#54598134).

Answer (score 2):

In your case, `&a` and `ptr` - they have same numerical value.

According to the specification, to print an address (either generated by using `&variable`, or stored in a pointer variable), always use `%p` format specifier, and cast the argument to `(void *)`. Anything else, is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Hi @SouravGhosh, Can you please help me understand a bit why casting to (void *) is required?