# Pointer layout in memory in C

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

I've recently been messing around with pointers and I would like to know a bit more about them, namely how they are organized in memory after using malloc for example.
So this is my understanding of it so far.

```
int **pointer = NULL;
```

Since we explicitly set the pointer to `NULL` it now points to the address `0x00`.

Now let's say we do

```
pointer = malloc(4*sizeof(int*));
```

Now we have `pointer` pointing to an address in memory - let's say `pointer` points to the address `0x0010`.

Let's say we then run a loop:

```
for (i = 0; i<4; i++) pointer[i] = malloc(3*sizeof(int));
```

Now, this is where it starts getting confusing to me. If we dereference `pointer`, by doing `*pointer` what do we get? Do we get `pointer[0]`? And if so, what is `pointer[0]`?

Continuing, now supposedly `pointer[i]` contains stored in it an address. And this is where it really starts confusing me and I will use images to better describe what I think is going on.

[image]

In the image you see, if it is correct, is `pointer[0]` referring to the box that has the address `0x0020` in it? What about `pointer[1]`?

If I were to print the contents of `pointer` would it show me `0x0010`? What about `pointer[0]`? Would it show me `0x0020`?

Thank you for taking the time to read my question and helping me understand the memory layout.

Comment: What is you problem?

Comment: The diagram looks plausible, but it's showing kind of a special case, where all the allocated blocks are contiguous and returned in increasing order. You should try drawing another one where they are in a different order and have gaps between them. Then put them side by side and see how they represent the same abstract structure.

Comment: @Olaf I'm just trying to understand if my understanding of how pointers work is correct. Things can get pretty confusing really fast and a solid base is always good.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley So what you're saying is that pointer[1] could be, for example, 0x00a0? Is there any logic to how malloc decides where the starting address of a block of allocated memory is? Or is it completely random?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Pointer Refresher

A pointer is just a numeric value that holds the address of a value of type `T`. This means that `T` can also be a pointer type, thus creating pointers-to-pointers, pointers-to-pointers-to-pointers, and crazy things like `char**********` - which is simply a pointer (`T*`) where `T` is a pointer to something else (`T = E*`) where `E` is a pointer to something else (and so on...).

Something to remember here is that a pointer itself is a value and thus takes space. More specifically, it's (usually) the size of the addressable space the CPU supports.

So for example, the 6502 processor (commonly found in old gaming consoles like the NES and Atari, as well as the Apple II, etc.) could only address 16 bits of memory, and thus its "pointers" were 16-bits in size.

So regardless of the underlying type, a pointer will [(usually)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1241314/510036) be as large as the addressable space.

Keep in mind that a pointer doesn't guarantee that it points to valid memory - it's simply a numeric value that happens to specify a location in memory.

### Array Refresher

An array is simply a series of `T` elements in contiguously addressable memory. The fact it's a "double pointer" (or pointer-to-a-pointer) is innocuous - it is still a regular pointer.

For example, allocating an array of 3 `T`'s will result in a memory block that is `3 * sizeof(T)` bytes long.

When you `malloc(...)` that memory, the pointer returned simply points to the first element.

```
T *array = malloc(3 * sizeof(T));
printf("%d\n", (&array[0] == &(*array))); // 1 (true)
```

Keep in mind that the subscript operator (the `[...]`) is basically just syntactic sugar for:

```
(*(array + sizeof(*array) * n)) // array[n]
```

### Arrays of Pointers

To sum all of this up, when you do

```
E **array = malloc(3 * sizeof(E*));
```

You're doing the same thing as

```
T *array = malloc(3 * sizeof(T));
```

where `T` is really `E*`.

Two things to remember about `malloc(...)`:

1. It doesn't initialize the memory with any specific values (use [`calloc`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_calloc.htm) for that)
2. It's not guaranteed (nor really even common) for the memory to be contiguous or adjacent to the memory returned by a previous call to `malloc`

Therefore, when you fill the previously created array-of-pointers with subsequent calls to `malloc()`, they might be in arbitrarily random places in memory.

All you're doing with your first `malloc()` call is simply creating the block of memory required to store `n` pointers. That's it.

### To answer your questions...

> If we dereference `pointer`, by doing `*pointer` what do we get? Do we get `pointer[0]`?

Since `pointer` is just a `int**`, and remembering that `malloc(...)` returns the address of the first byte in the block of memory you allocated, `*pointer` will indeed evaluate to `pointer[0]`.

> And if so, what is `pointer[0]`?

Again, since `pointer` as the type `int**`, then `pointer[0]` will return a value type of `int*` with the numeric contents of the first `sizeof(int*)` bytes in the memory block pointed to by `pointer`.

> If I were to print the contents of `pointer` would it show me `0x0010`?

If by "printing the contents" you mean `printf("%p\n", (void*) pointer)`, then no.

Since you `malloc()`'d the memory block that `pointer` points to, `pointer` *itself* is just a value with the size of `sizeof(int**)`, and thus will hold the address (as a numeric value) where the block of memory you `malloc()`'d resides.

So the above `printf()` call will simply print that value out.

> What about `pointer[0]`?

Again assuming you mean `printf("%p\n", (void*) pointer[0])`, then you'll get a slightly different output.

Since `pointer[0]` is the equivalent of `*pointer`, and thus causes `pointer` to be dereferenced, you'll get a value of `int*` and thus the pointer value that is stored in the first element.

You would need to further dereference that pointer to get the numeric value stored in the first integer that you allocated; for example:

```
printf("%d\n", **pointer);
// or
printf("%d\n", *pointer[0]);
// or even
printf("%d\n", pointer[0][0]); // though this isn't recommended
                               // for readability's sake since
                               // `pointer[0]` isn't an array but
                               // instead a pointer to a single `int`.
```

Comment: I know I marked this answer as correct already but I failed to understand why doing printf("%p", (void*)pointer) wouldn't show me, in this case, 0x0010. I mean, what would it show me?

Comment: @Pedro Oh, I misread your question. In that particular case, it would. In normal circumstances it would show a random pointer address

Answer (score 0):

> If I dereference `pointer`, by doing `*pointer` what do I get? `pointer[0]`?

Yes.

> And if so, what is `pointer[0]`?

With your definitions: `0x0020`.

> In the image you see, if it is correct

It seems correct to me.

> is `pointer[0]` referring to the box that has the address `0x0020` in it?

Still yes.

> What about `pointer[1]`?

At this point, I think you can guess that it woud show: `0x002c`.

## To go further

If you want to check how memory is managed and what pointers look like you can use `gdb`. It allows running a program step by step and performing various operations such as showing the content of variables. Here is the main page for [GNU gdb](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/). A quick internet search should let you find numerous `gdb` tutorials.

You can also show the address of a pointer in c by using a printf line:

```
int *plop = NULL;
fprintf(stdout, "%p\n", (void *)pointer);
```

*Note: don't forget to include `<stdio.h>`*

Comment: The fprintf invokes undefined behaviour. `%p` expects a `void *`. (unrelated: why not use `printf`??)

Comment: @Olaf What do you mean by undefined behaviour? It worked fine for me. Maybe trying to print the address of NULL is not the best idea. On my machine it shows (nil). You can try assigning `plop` to an allocated memory zone, it will show its address.

Comment: @silel As in the standard specifies you need to pass a `void*` because not all pointer sizes are the same.

Comment: @silel: You pass a wrong type for this conversion type specifier. What is unclear about undefined behaviour? "the code works" is a non sequitur.

Comment: Ok so I did some digging and many other posts in SO actually mention the same rule "need to cast to void *" for `%p`. If possible, I would very much like some reference for that. Anything I have searched points back to SO.

Comment: @Olaf why use `fprintf` instead of `printf`. Mostly habit, some say it is also easier to switch from `stdout` to `stderr` this way.

Comment: @Olaf The man page of fprintf states _p    The void * pointer argument is printed in hexadecimal (as if by %#x or %#lx)._ but it does not explain __why__ a cast is necessary. I am currently reading the C standard, it may be that I am missing something but I fail to see __why__ the cast is needed.

Comment: @silel: read on, passing the wrong type to a parameter is undefined behaviour is one of the things you should have learned in the first lesson about functions.

Comment: @Olaf Please back your statements with actual references. [This versions of the standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) is what motivates my point. Your last statement is clearly invalidated by section 6.9.1 - point 10 of the linked document. Good day to you.

Comment: @silel: Last post, this is getting nowhere: 1) This is not the standard, but an early draft. Use the final draft as a reference if you can#t/don't want to affort buying the standard document (this is completely acceptable, I can assure there are two unrelated differences only). 2) You violate the effective type rule. This is one of the most important sections of the whole document. Every C programmer should be expected to be at least aware of its basic implications. You are effectively telling it does not matter which type you pass to a function parameter!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141815/discussion-between-silel-and-olaf).

Comment: @silel-- `fprintf()` takes a variable number of arguments, and the arguments that follow the format string can be of _any type_. There is no type specified in the function prototype to convert these arguments. The function itself must use the conversion specifiers from the format string, and in the case of `%p`, `(void *)` is expected. [A mismatch between argument type and conversion specifier leads to undefined behavior](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p9).

Comment: See also [§6.5.2.2 7 of the C11 Draft Standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.2p7): "The ellipsis notation in a function prototype declarator causes argument type conversion to stop after the last declared parameter. The default argument promotions are performed on trailing arguments."

Comment: @DavidBowling Thank you very much!