# sizeof union in C

Tags: c, unions

The sizeof a union is equal to the size of the largest member in it. But in the following union, the size is being shown to be 8 Bytes. Size of int and float is 4 Bytes. Why does it show 8 Bytes?

```
union data {
    int i;
    float f;
    char *str;
};
```

Comment: Did you check the size of the char*? It could be the cause.

Comment: Maybe try printing the `sizeof` each of the elements separately as one of them is obviously 8 bytes

Comment: I have X, Y and Z. This is causing W. I've checked X, Y and they are not the cause of W. What could cause W?

Comment: *Size of int and float is 4 Bytes.* How did you determine this? And what about the `char *`?

Comment: Also consider the alignment problem! Try using __packed

Comment: @JonnySchubert Its `union`, not a `struct`.  How would packing affect a `union`?

Comment: `char * str` has 8 bytes length in 64 bits CPU.

Comment: @SergioFormiggini It has a pretty loose relation to the CPU bitness.

Comment: What kind of machine architecture and compiler are you using

Comment: @EugeneSh. On my I3 with Linux 64 the pointers are 8 byte length. On the other hand is very easy to verify what the compiler generates. I'm sure that the result is due to the pointer length!

Comment: All three `i`, `f`, and `str` are members of `union data`.

Comment: minus for unbelievable laziness.  You wrote this silly post, wasted our time and you did not check what your pointer size is.

Comment: @SergioFormiggini What is happening is not related to what *might* happen. Moreover, sizes to different types *on the same machine* are not guaranteed to be the same size. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241205/are-all-data-pointers-the-same-size-in-one-platform-for-all-data-types

Comment: @Eugene Sh. Another useless discussion. Ridiculous topic .Graet companion

Comment: If `int` and `float` are 4 bytes wide on your system, but the size of your union is 8 bytes wide, then it's pretty clear that on your system `char *` is 8 bytes wide.

Comment: @EugeneSh. It was long ago I saw such a burning sarcasm! :D

Answer (score 6):

sizeof(char *) is the size of the pointer.
It's usually 4 for 32-bit machine, and 8 for 64-bit machine.
Given your result, I take it you're on a 64-bit machine.

Answer (score 6):

```
#include <stdio.h>

union data_t {
  int i;
  float f;
  char *str;
};

int main()
{
  union data_t data;
  printf("%zu\n%zu\n%zu\n", sizeof (data.i), sizeof (data.f), sizeof (data.str));
  printf("\nsizeof(char*): %zu\nsizeof(char): %zu\n", sizeof(char *), sizeof(char));
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./a.out 
4
4
8

sizeof(char*): 8
sizeof(char): 1
```

Comment: @chux Fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

**Size of union = size of the largest data type used**

The memory occupied by a union will be large enough to hold the largest member of the union. It doesn't matter what is currently in use. For example,

```
union Data 
 {
   int i;
   float f;
   char str[20];
 } data;
```

Now, a variable of Data type can store an integer, a floating-point number, or a string of characters. It means a single variable, i.e., same memory location, can be used to store multiple types of data. Data type will occupy 20 bytes of memory space because this is the maximum space which can be occupied by a character string.

Answer (score 2):

Try the code below on a Windows 64/Linux 64 and the result should be 8, on a 32 bit system should be 4.

```
int main(void)
{
    char * str;

    printf("%d\n",sizeof(str));

    return 0;

}
```