# what does the sizeof(&a[0]) mean for an array 'a' of int?

Tags: c, arrays, sizeof

so if i run this code it will give the expected answer of `9`

```
int main()
{
    int a[]={9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1};
    int n=sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]); printf("%d", n);
}
```

but if i change `sizeof(a[0])` to `sizeof(&a[0])`..then the output is `4`
Why does this happen? Exactly what does the computer 'think' when it is given `sizeof(&a[0])`?

Comment: `a[0]` is an `int`, therefore `&a[0]` is a *pointer* to `int` (e.g. a pointer to the first element of `a`) So, `sizeof(&a[0])` is what? `sizeof (a_pointer)`.

Comment: so this means that it is returning the number of bytes of an int pointer, right?

Comment: Yep -- you got it (8-bytes on x86_64 or 4-bytes on x86) If the `"a pointer"` is confusing (you had to name the array `a`...) it is simply `sizeof (pointer)`

Comment: `&anything` gets the variable's pointer, whatever type this variable is. All pointers have the same size (8 bytes for 64-bit architecture, 4 bytes for 32-bit).

Comment: @Havenard See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241205/are-all-data-pointers-the-same-size-in-one-platform-for-all-data-types

Comment: @4386427 I know, but, while it is technically true, it's only the case on some microcontrollers where you don't even get a real ANSI C compiler. It's not even worth taking this random factoid in consideration for 99.99% of applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&a[0]` on an array `a` in C yields the address of its first element. On a 16-bit system, `sizeof` of that address is most likely 2, on a 32-bit system, `sizeof` that address it is 4, and, on a 64-bit system, it is 8.