# Which one occupies less memory? A pair<type,type> or two 'type' variables

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, memory-management

Which of these two solutions occupies less memory?

- `short X; short Y;`
- `pair<short,short> Coords;`

Comment: I am quite sure that both possibilities generally take the same amount of memory. Depending on the compiler, there may be some uncommon situations where there is a slight difference. However, I wouldn't worry about that.

Comment: Why not just the `pair`? What is the point of `array<pair, 1>`?

Comment: There may be differences in the number of instructions generated for each case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the following code in `C++2a(GNU)` compiler:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  short X;
  array<pair<short, short>, 1> Coords;

  cout << sizeof(X) << endl;
  cout << sizeof(Coords) << endl;
}
```

It seems that it is same thing, 1 `short` is 2 bytes, the `array` is 4 bytes.

If we try the addresses also the same size:

```
cout << sizeof(&X) << endl;
cout << sizeof(&Coords) << endl;
```

8 bytes each.

Comment: I'm not sure the second check is necessary, given that (nowadays) all pointers [generally have the same size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1241314/7366707). If any sort of difference is apparent it would be due to the underlying hardware and not the data type itself.

Comment: @Moira, yes you're right, but, it never hurts to double check :)

Answer (score 4):

The size of a `short` is platform, compiler and architecture dependent but assuming its size is 2 bytes, both will occupy 4 bytes in memory.

```
static_assert(sizeof(std::array<std::pair<short, short>, 1>) == sizeof(short[2]))
```

hence why the static assertion doesn't fail here

Comment: The language definition does not require that this be true. It depends **entirely** on the compiler.