# How can I allocate a pointer to a struct in C?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct foo{
        int a;
};

int main(int argc, char * * argv){
        struct foo * bar = malloc(sizeof(struct foo));
        free(bar);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Wouldn't this cause [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) according to the standard? If so, what should I do instead to adhere to the standard?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1241314/13959281

Comment: *Wouldn't this cause undefined behavior*. In what way do you think it causes UB? Can you please explain in more detail where and why you think there is a problem in this code? And what exactly does the other post referenced have to do with your question?

Comment: @kaylum The other post referenced talks about how different pointer types may have different sizes. I was wondering if there was a possibility that the void * that malloc returns would have a different size than struct foo *. If it were, then that should be undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Suggest you [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65967232/edit) your question with that clarification as it really isn't very clear as currently stated.

Comment: @JohnFriendson Hi, could add a text to why you added the link https://stackoverflow.com/a/1241314/13959281

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the question is what will happen if the `malloc` fails and  `bar` will be assigned `NULL`, then the answer is: nothing will happen when `free` is called. `free` function checks if the pointer passed is `NULL`. If the pointer is `NULL` no action is taken. So there is no UB here.

As a general remark: it is safer (or at least less error-prone) if instead of types the actual objects are used:

```
struct foo * bar = malloc(sizeof(*bar));
```

#EDIT#

OPs comment clarifies the question. The size of pointer in the implementation does not matter as C standard guarantees that any pointer to object type (not function pointer) can be converted to `void *` and `void *` can be converted to any type of pointer. How it is actually done is left to the implementation. So it is 100% safe as it is guaranteed by the C standard.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question.


https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/malloc.html

It says more regarding this here, that in particular, what malloc returns may be casted to any type.